# How to stop Backbone sending calculated values back to the server when doing model.save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

Say I have a `person` model, with a `name` attribute.

Server-side, when I create a `JSON` representation of the model, I include a calculated value:

```
name: 'Jack'
name_backwards: 'kcaJ' # example
```

Client-side, when I do `backbone_model.save(attributes)`, it includes `name_backwards` in the object it sends to the server. This isn't ideal, because it doesn't correspond to an actual attribute on the server.

`PATCH` is not an option because I'm using Rails 3.2. Is there any way around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems a bit odd to me that your server is sending something out that it won't accept back. I see two options:

1. Filtering out an incoming `name_backwards` in your controller.
2. Stop sending `name_backwards` and let the client deal with it.

**1** is easy, just delete `:name_backwards` from the appropriate part of `params`.

**2** is a little more involved. First you'd stop adding `name_backwards` to the JSON that goes out. Then you could add `name_backwards` in your model's [`parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse):

```
parse: function(response) {
    response.name_backwards = reverse(response.name);
    return response;
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16776380/479863) for a reliable way to reverse a string in JavaScript.

Then you'll want to ignore `name_backwards` in your model's [`toJSON`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON):

```
toJSON: function() {
    var o = _(this.attributes).clone(); // This is what the standard toJSON does.
    delete o.name_backwards;
    return o;
}
```

Then add a `serialize` method to use instead of `toJSON` when you're feeding your models to your templates:

```
serialize: function() {
    return _(this.attributes).clone();
}
```

You can easily patch `serialize` into `Backbone.Model.prototype` if you want an easy way to have a consistent interface between your models and templates.

Answer (score 0):

Override the `toJSON` method in your `Backbone.Model` subclass and select only the canonical fields from `this.attributes`.

Comment: Any fields that are not included in the overridden toJSON don't seem to be available for other uses either. I need the calculated values for display purposes, I just don't want to send them back to the server in the update.

Comment: Yes, as @mu points out, backbone doesn't provide distinct methods meaning "toJSON for templating" and "toJSON for the API". You may want to consider the presenter design pattern and leave your models focused on dealing with the canonical data. But as is often the case with backbone questions the answer comes down to "yes you can get it to do that but you have to write a bunch of code".