# how to reverse string without using any built in functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

can anyone please tell me how to reverse a given string without using **ANY** built in functions?

I have tried following ones, but in all cases there is some built in functions involved

```
function reverseString(str){        
    return str.split("").reverse().join("");    
}
reverseString("I love coding");

function reverseString(str){
    var myArray = [];
    for(var i = 0; i <= str.length; i++ ){
        myArray.push(str.charAt(str.length - i));
    }
    return myArray.join("");
}
reverseString("I love coding");

function reverseString(str){
    var reversedString = '';
    for(var i = str.length -1 ; i >= 0; i--){
        reversedString += str[i];
    }

    return reversedString;
}
reverseString("I love coding");

function reverseString(str){
    var newArray = [];
    for(var i = str.length -1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++){
        newArray[j] = str[i];
    }
    return newArray.join("");
}
reverseString("I love coding");
```

Comment: There is no built-in function involved in your 3rd example.

Comment: I don't want to use any extra var also. Is it possible?

Comment: thirs function() is perfect . no built in function is there except join()...

Comment: No, it is not possible. Strings are immutable, so you'll have to build a new string.

Comment: for swapping you need extra var|array. I am trying to avoid all those things. @ravi

Comment: None of the above algorithms account for Unicode combing characters or surrogate pairs, and doing so without using ***ANY** built in function* seems unlikely. See e.g. https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode#reversing-strings and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16776380) to [Reversing a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1611427) for a discussion of how to reverse such sequences correctly.

Answer (score 0):

to comply with requirement of no natives and no var declaration I've cheated.

named arguments can be reassigned.

```
var s = 'foobar';

function r(e,v,r){
  for(r=e.length,v='';r;)v+=e[--r];return v;    
}

console.log(r(s));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple

```
var name = 'bhaurao';
var newName = '';
for(i in name){
  newName = name[i] + newName;

}
console.log("reverse string is "+newName);
```

You can check example here [Click here](http://jsbin.com/depahuqafo/edit?js,console)