# What is the most efficient way to iterate over javascript object?

Tags: ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I need to iterate over javascript big object in memory so often for generate nested json data and insert into db. The object structure is like this:

```
var obj = {
    "30": { "7": { "date1": { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}}},
    "29": { "8": { "date2": { "key1": "value1"}}},  
    "28": { "6": { "date3": { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"}}}   
};
```

actually I use this aproach for iterate over the object for change nesting levels

```
Object.keys(obj).map((number1) => {
    const number1Obj = obj[number1];
    Object.keys(number1Obj).map((number2) => {
        const number2Obj = number1Obj[number2];
        Object.keys(number2Obj).map((date) => {
            const dateObj = number2Obj[date];
            console.log(number1);
            console.log(number2);
            console.log(date);
            Object.keys(dateObj).map((key) => {
                console.log(`           ${key}:${dateObj[key]}`);
            });
        });
     });
  });
```

Is there a more efficient way of iterate over the object and its properties?
[running example](https://plnkr.co/edit/s98JcZ3pILKNb6zDbprt?p=preview)

Comment: Is this a performance bottleneck in your app, or is this premature optimization? It's better to have clear understandable code for the most part and focus your optimizations on the real issues later.

Comment: Thanks for the advice , currently It isn't a problem but I like to have thought my code in terms of efficiency.

Comment: If you're worried about performance (but why are you?), then a `for` loop will always be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this answer relevant, but not sure about performance issues.

[Iterate through Nested JavaScript Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085004/iterate-through-nested-javascript-objects)

Comment: Thanks but my problem is not iterate is the performance, I'm looking for the best way.