# How to iterate through a nested object and putting values into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I created a nested object that holds the following format:

```
var lineMap = {
  2016: {
    Hemoglobin: 33 ,
    Lysozyme: 33 ,
    Myoglobin: 47 ,
    DNA: 13 ,
    Cytochrome C: 33
  },
  2017: {
    Hemoglobin: 8 ,
    Lysozyme: 47 ,
    Myoglobin: 8 ,
    DNA: 12 ,
    Cytochrome C: 33
  },
  2018: {
    Hemoglobin: 8 ,
    Lysozyme: 33 ,
    Myoglobin: 47 ,
    DNA: 12 ,
    Cytochrome C: 13
  },
  2019: {
    Hemoglobin: 8 ,
    Lysozyme: 8 ,
    Myoglobin: 47 ,
    DNA: 8 ,
    Cytochrome C: 47
  }
}
```

And I'd like to place each year's item count into its own index of an array such that:

```
var arr = [
  [33, 33, 47, 13, 33],
  [8, 47, 8, 12, 33],
  [8, 33, 47, 12, 13],
  [8, 8, 47, 8, 47]
]
```

I have tried with creating a nested for loop to iterate through the nested object `lineMap`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < year.length; i ++){
  for (var j = 0; j < itemName.length; j++){
    temp_arr[j] = lineMap[year[i]][itemName[j]];
  }
  console.log("Index: " + i  + "\n" + temp_arr);
  arr[i] = temp_arr;
}
console.log(arr);
```

At the 5th line (`console.log(temp_arr)`), the console printed out what I expected--an array of the item count of its respective iteration:

```
'Index: 0
33,33,47,13,33'
'Index: 1
8,47,8,12,33'
'Index: 2
8,33,47,12,13'
'Index: 3
8,8,47,8,47'
```

However, at the 8th line (`console.log(arr)`), I am not receiving my expected output. Instead, I am getting:

```
var arr = [
  [8, 8, 47, 8, 47],
  [8, 8, 47, 8, 47],
  [8, 8, 47, 8, 47],
  [8, 8, 47, 8, 47]
]
```

Comment: Your linemap is json, maybe try including that info, you can iterate through json objects much more efficiently than that. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085004/iterate-through-nested-javascript-objects

Comment: Without order you can use `Object.values(lineMap).map(Object.values)`

Comment: @RedaDrissi - *"Your linemap is json"* No, it isn't. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: @MaheerAli - I'm sure we've had this conversation before. :-) The order of the properties in JavaScript objects **is** defined, now, so "you can't get them in order" is incorrect. You *shouldn't* get them in order, yes, but... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder pardon my language abuse, linemap is similar to a parsed JSON string, so it can be iterated through much more efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a warning: The order of the properties in those objects *is* defined, now, as of ES2015, but relying on that order is generally a bad idea. Also, you seem to be using only ES5 level features, which don't define the order.

So the best way, without relying on order, is to give yourself an array of the property names in the order you want them in your result arrays:

```
var keys = [
    "Hemoglobin",
    "Lysozyme",
    "Myoglobin",
    "DNA",
    "Cytochrome C"
];
```

Then something like this (see comments):

```
// Loop through the years sorted lexicographically, building the result array
var arr = Object.keys(lineMap).sort().map(function(mainKey) {
    // Loop through the property names in the defined order, building
    // each inner array
    var entry = lineMap[mainKey];
    return keys.map(function(key) {
        return entry[key];
    });
});
```

Live Example:

```js
var keys = [
    "Hemoglobin",
    "Lysozyme",
    "Myoglobin",
    "DNA",
    "Cytochrome C"
];
var lineMap = {
  2016: {
    Hemoglobin: 33 ,
    Lysozyme: 33 ,
    Myoglobin: 47 ,
    DNA: 13 ,
    "Cytochrome C": 33
  },
  2017: {
    Hemoglobin: 8 ,
    Lysozyme: 47 ,
    Myoglobin: 8 ,
    DNA: 12 ,
    "Cytochrome C": 33
  },
  2018: {
    Hemoglobin: 8 ,
    Lysozyme: 33 ,
    Myoglobin: 47 ,
    DNA: 12 ,
    "Cytochrome C": 13
  },
  2019: {
    Hemoglobin: 8 ,
    Lysozyme: 8 ,
    Myoglobin: 47 ,
    DNA: 8 ,
    "Cytochrome C": 47
  }
};

// Loop through the years sorted lexicographically, building the
// result array
var arr = Object.keys(lineMap).sort().map(function(mainKey) {
    // Loop through the property names in the defined order, building
    // each inner array
    var entry = lineMap[mainKey];
    return keys.map(function(key) {
        return entry[key];
    });
});

console.log(arr);
```

If you want the years in numeric order, just add a callback to the `sort`:

```
.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; })
```

Tackling it in an ES2015+ world, I'd still keep the separate list of keys in the order you want them, so not a lot changes, it just gets a bit more concise:

```
const arr = Object.entries(lineMap)
    .sort(([a], [b]) => a.localeCompare(b))
    .map(([_, entry]) => keys.map(key => entry[key]));
```

Live Example:

```js
const keys = [
    "Hemoglobin",
    "Lysozyme",
    "Myoglobin",
    "DNA",
    "Cytochrome C"
];
const lineMap = {
  2016: {
    Hemoglobin: 33 ,
    Lysozyme: 33 ,
    Myoglobin: 47 ,
    DNA: 13 ,
    "Cytochrome C": 33
  },
  2017: {
    Hemoglobin: 8 ,
    Lysozyme: 47 ,
    Myoglobin: 8 ,
    DNA: 12 ,
    "Cytochrome C": 33
  },
  2018: {
    Hemoglobin: 8 ,
    Lysozyme: 33 ,
    Myoglobin: 47 ,
    DNA: 12 ,
    "Cytochrome C": 13
  },
  2019: {
    Hemoglobin: 8 ,
    Lysozyme: 8 ,
    Myoglobin: 47 ,
    DNA: 8 ,
    "Cytochrome C": 47
  }
};

const arr = Object.entries(lineMap)
    .sort(([a], [b]) => a.localeCompare(b))
    .map(([_, entry]) => keys.map(key => entry[key]));

console.log(arr);
```

That takes advantage of [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), and [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

And again, if you want those years in numeric order:

```
const arr = Object.entries(lineMap)
    .sort(([a], [b]) => a - b)
    .map(([_, entry]) => keys.map(key => entry[key]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue looks like the problem is with `arr[i] = temp_arr;` and sharing the same array reference. You need to start with a new array on each iteration. Or you need to clone it when copying it. `arr[i] = temp_arr.slice(0)`

Object.entries and map() will make your job easier.

```js
var lineMap = {
  2016: {
    Hemoglobin: 33,
    Lysozyme: 33,
    Myoglobin: 47,
    DNA: 13,
    'Cytochrome C': 33
  },
  2017: {
    Hemoglobin: 8,
    Lysozyme: 47,
    Myoglobin: 8,
    DNA: 12,
    'Cytochrome C': 33
  },
  2018: {
    Hemoglobin: 8,
    Lysozyme: 33,
    Myoglobin: 47,
    DNA: 12,
    'Cytochrome C': 13
  },
  2019: {
    Hemoglobin: 8,
    Lysozyme: 8,
    Myoglobin: 47,
    DNA: 8,
    'Cytochrome C': 47
  }
}

console.log(Object.values(lineMap).map(o=>Object.values(o)))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using the exact same array every time, so when you do `arr[i] = temp_arr` you are assigning the same copy to each position of `arr`. You should create a new array each time. Secondly, you cannot know the order of an object's keys, there is no guarantee that the keys will be ordered when iterating over them. With this said, you could still use a fixed list of keys or sort them first.

```
let orderedKeys = ['Hemoglobin', 'Lysozyme', 'Myoglobin', 'DNA', 'Cytochrome C'];
let arr = Object.values(lineMap).map(el => orderedKeys.map(k => el[k]))
```

Result:

```
> arr
0: [33, 33, 47, 13, 33]
1: [8, 47, 8, 12, 33]
2: [8, 33, 47, 12, 13]
3: [8, 8, 47, 8, 47]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with ES6 syntax this will do the trick:

```
let result = [];
Object.values(lineMap).map(obj =>result.push(Object.values(obj)))
```

This will get you an array of arrays like you wanted. If you prefer a single array with all the results you can spread the second `Object.values(obj)` like so:

```
Object.values(lineMap).map(obj =>result.push(...Object.values(obj)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a function called **yearsItemCount();** Just call this and it will return what you want... Although it's O(N^2)

```
yearsItemCount = () => {

    let finalArr = []

      for(var line in lineMap) {
          let arr = [];
        for(var i in lineMap[line]) {
          arr.push(lineMap[line][i])
        }
        finalArr.push(arr);
      }
      return finalArr;
    }
```

or

```
Object.values(lineMap).map((a, b) => {
  return Object.values(a);
})
```

I don't know what's faster.