# How to iterate through array of objects and stringify

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

I've been at this for a bit trying to come up with a solution. I have tested a handful of stack solutions to iterate through nested objects but haven't gotten this to work correctly. My data structure is below.

I've been trying to first off iterate through nested objects which this stack seemed to be similar to mine.

[Iterate through Nested JavaScript Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085004/iterate-through-nested-javascript-objects)

However, when I'm in my for loop getting access to geo, value object to grab all of its properties, ip, hostname, city etc I'm coming up empty handed with undefined. Here's a code snippet of what I've tried below.

I'm trying to take all of the keys and values in this entire object and stringify them into a beautiful parameter string to send over to the server in an ajax request.

```
for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
    var o = myarray[i];
    if (o.name === "geo") {

        o.value.ip;
    }
}
```

```
0: {name: "firstname", value: "John"}
1: {name: "lastname", value: "Smith"}
2: {name: "email", value: "asddas@gmail.com"}
3: {name: "password", value: "asdsdadasads"}
4: {name: "paypal_email", value: "asdsa@gmail.com"}
5: {name: "phone", value: "1234567894"}
6: {name: "geo",value: " 
{"ip":"111.111.111.111","hostname":"rr.com","city":"MyCity","region":"Ohio","country":"US","loc":"41.34.23","org":"Inc","postal":"1234","timezone":"America/New_York","readme":"https://www.google.com"}"
__proto__: Object
length: 7
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: `I'm coming up empty handed with undefined` Is there an error message, or what value is undefined? Can you successfully get inside the `if` statement?

Comment: Maybe give us the simplify myarray example and what's the result that you are looking for

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have gotten the if to evaluate true on that but when  tri to get to the nested value it shows up as undefined in the debugger.

Comment: @GlenK - Sorry, I think I misunderstood what you're asking for. I'm lookin to take the object I posted and iterate through each property, even the nested properties, and turn then into a string like so firstname=john&lastname=smith&ip=111.111.111.11&hostname=rr.com etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the structure of the `geo` object is odd:

```
name: "geo",value: "{"ip":"111.111.111.111","hostname":"rr.com","city":"MyCity","region":"Ohio","country":"US","loc":"41.34.23","org":"Inc","postal":"1234","timezone":"America/New_York","readme":"https://www.google.com"}"
```

The value looks to be a *string* in JSON notation. You'll have to parse it first in order to look up properties on it:

```
if (o.name === "geo") {
    const nestedObj = JSON.parse(o.value);
    console.log(nestedObj.ip);
}
```

You might also consider fixing whatever's serving you that object so that the value is an actual object - if that's possible (it may not be, but it would make the code make a lot more sense).

You can also consider using `.find` instead of a `for` loop, to make the code shorter and more elegant:

```
const json = myarray.find(({ name }) => name === 'geo').value;
const nestedObj = JSON.parse(json);
```

(if the `geo` object may not exist, test for `undefined` first, of course)

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that the `value` field for the object with the `name` of "geo" is a JSON string.

Because the `value` is a string, you won't be able to directly access the `ip` field without first parsing that string to an object:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
    var o = myarray[i];
    if (o.name === "geo") {

        /* "Convert" the JSON string in o.value to the corresponding object */
        const valueObject = JSON.parse(o.value);
        /* The ip field can now be accessed from the valueObject, parsed from
        the JSON string in o.value */
        console.log(valueObject.ip);
    }
}
```