# How to modify the property of nested object using key detail

Tags: javascript, object

I have a nested object having structure like this:

```
let obj = {
  id1: {
    key1: value1,
    files: {
      fileid1: {},
      fileid2: {}
    }
  },
  id2: {
    key1: value1,
    files: {
      fileid3: {},
      fileid4: {}
    }
  }
}
```

I have an existing file id , I need to find that file id from this object and update the data of the object.
let say I have file id that is equal to **fileid3**
How can I do this ?

Comment: So you just want to get the object corresponding to `fileid3`?

Comment: @nickzoum yes, i need to update the key value pairs for fileid3 object

Answer (score 1):

```js
let obj = {
    id1: {
        key1: "value1",
        files: {
            fileid1: {},
            fileid2: {}
        }
    },
    id2: {
        key1: "value1",
        files: {
            fileid3: {},
            fileid4: {}
        }
    }
}

function changeObj(obj, field, value) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {

        if (obj[key].files.hasOwnProperty(field))
            obj[key].files[field] = value;

    });
    return obj;
}

console.log(changeObj(obj, "fileid3", "new Value"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on the [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) of your object. For each value (ie object), you can check whether the `.files` object has the property of the `fileid` you pass into your function. If it does you can return `true` by using [`.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty). You can then use `.files[id]` on the return value of `.find()` to get your object:

```js
const obj = { id1: { key1: "value1", files: { fileid1: {}, fileid2: {} } }, id2: { key1: "value1", files: { fileid3: {}, fileid4: {} } } };

const findObjectByFile = (obj, id) => 
  (Object.values(obj).find(({files}) => files.hasOwnProperty(id)) || {files: {}}).files[id];
 
const file_obj = findObjectByFile(obj, "fileid");
file_obj.foo = "bar";
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Object.values` to iterate through the first level of the object and check if the `files` object contains the property you are looking for using the `in` operator.

```js
let obj = {
  id1: {
    key1: "value1",
    files: {
      fileid1: {},
      fileid2: {}
    }
  },
  id2: {
    key1: "value1",
    files: {
      fileid3: {},
      fileid4: {}
    }
  }
};

editFileID("fileid3", "new value");
console.log(obj.id2.files.fileid3);

function editFileID(fileID, newValue) {
  Object.values(obj).some(function(obj) {
    if (fileID in obj.files) {
      obj.files[fileID] = newValue;
      return true;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example JSON object:

```
const myJSONExample = {
  id1: {
    key1: "value1",
    files: {
      fileid1: "2",
      fileid2: "3"
    }
  },
  id2: {
    key1: "value1",
    files: {
      fileid3: "4",
      fileid4: "5"
    }
  }
}
```

Now iterate over the object, find your specific key and update its value. If a key is a nested object, we use recursion.

```
const iterate = (obj) => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {

    if(key == 'fileid3'){
      obj[key] = 'asd';
    }
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
            iterate(obj[key])
        }
    })

}

iterate(myJSONExample);
console.log(myJSONExample);
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
{ 
  id1: 
     { 
       key1: 'value1', 
       files: 
            { fileid1: '2', fileid2: '3' }
     },  
  id2: 
     { 
       key1: 'value1', 
       files: 
           { fileid3: 'asd', fileid4: '5'} 
     } 
 }
```

**`fileid3` value has been updated**

reference link: [Iterate through Nested JavaScript Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085004/iterate-through-nested-javascript-objects)