# How to refactor code for looping through object using typescript and react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to loop through the object to check if there is atleast orders color or subProducts orders color is black or red.

if there is atleast one orders color or subProducts orders color is black or red then should hide the Hide me button.

below is the code,

```
function Parent() {
    const product = {
        items: [
            {
                id: '1',
                orders: [
                    {
                        id: '1',
                        color: 'red',
                    }, 
                    {
                        id: '2',
                        color: 'green',
                    }
                ],

                subProducts: [
                    {
                        id: '1',
                        orders: [
                            {
                                id: '4',
                                color: 'green',
                            }
                        ],
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                id: '2',
                orders: [
                    {
                        id: '3',
                        color: 'black',
                     },
                     {
                         id: '4',
                         color: 'blue',
                     }
                ],
                subProducts: [
                    {
                        id: '2',
                        orders: [
                            {
                                id: '5',
                                color: 'green',
                            }, 
                            {
                                id: '6',
                                color: 'black',
                            }
                        ],
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

    return (
        < Menu > Hide me <  / Menu > 
    );
}
```

**What i have tried?**

```
function Parent() {
    const checkArray = (array: any[]) => {
        for (const item of array) {
            if (item.color === 'black' || item.color === 'red') {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };
    const output = () => {
    let hideBool = false;
        if (product.items) {
            for (const item of product.items) {
                if (hideBool) {
                    break;
                }
                if (item.orders) {
                    hideBool = checkArray(item.orders);
                }
                if (!hideBool) {
                    if (item.subProducts) {
                        for (const subProduct of item.subProducts) {
                            if (subProduct.orders) {
                                hideBool = checkArray(subProduct.orders);
                            }
                            if (hideBool) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
           }
       }
       return hideBool;
    };

    const isColor = output();
    return (
        {!isColor && 
            <Menu> Hide me </Menu>
        }
    );
}
```

The above snippet works. but the code looks clumsy with lots of if conditions. how can this snippet be further refactored using typescript and react.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54272512/6548802

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some instead of for loop. It takes less lines of codes but whether it is more readable is for debate.

```
const shouldHide = items.some(item =>
 //Check if item.orders have the color
 item.orders && item.orders.some(order =>
    order.color === "black" || order.color === "red") ||
 //Check if item.subProducts.orders have the color    
 item.subProducts && item.subProducts.some(subProduct =>
    subProduct.orders && subProduct.orders.some(order =>
        order.color === "black" || order.color === "red"
    ))
)
```

Comment: thanks. but it gives error near items.some, item.orders.some, item.subProducts.some that object could be possibly undefined.

Comment: Added undefined checks.