# Loop object with an object

Tags: javascript

How can I loop my object inside an object? I have an address object inside of a person object. I can iterate the key and value of a person object.

```
let obj = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  age: 23,
  gender: 'Male',
  address: {
    street: 'SampleStreetName',
    province: 'SampleProvinceName',
    city: 'SampleCityName',
  },
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
  console.log(`${key}: `, obj[key]);
});
```

**I want my output like this:**

```
name:  John Doe
age:  23
gender:  Male
street: SampleStreetName 
province: SampleProvinceName 
city: SampleCityName
```

**This is my actual output:**

```
name:  John Doe
age:  23
gender:  Male
address:  {street: 'SampleStreetName', province: 'SampleProvinceName', city: 'SampleCityName'}
```

Comment: [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085004/iterate-through-nested-javascript-objects)

Comment: That is not what I looking for

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is. The output you want is 100% achievable with the info in the answers to that question.