# How to Remove Specific Text / String Out of Array Object Values

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Node.js 16.17 and Express.

Forgive me if this is answered elsewhere, if a solution exists elsewhere, please point me in that direction.

On my server side, I have an array with objects with properties and their values. I want to be able to remove specific text/string from the property values.

**What I Have**

I currently have an array with objects (and sometimes arrays and object nested within):

```
DataArray = 
[
  {
    page: {
      results: [
        {
          id: '1234',
          title: 'TextIWantA **(Text) I Dont Want**',
          children: {
            page: {
              results: [
                {
                  id: '5678',
                  title: 'ChildA TextIWant **(Text I) Dont Want**',
                },
                {
                  id: '9101',
                  title: 'ChildB TextIWant **(Text I) Dont Want**',
                  children: {
                    page: {
                      results: [
                        {
                          id: 'abcd',
                          title: 'GrandchildA TextIWant **(Text I (Dont) Want**',
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          id: '1121',
          title: 'TextIWantB **(Text) I Dont Want**',
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I am able to flatten this structure with this function:

```
function flatten(arr) {
  const flattened = []
  for (const { children, ...element } of arr) {
    flattened.push(element)
    if (children) {
      flattened.push(...flatten(children.page.results))
    }
  }
  return flattened;
}

const flat = [{ page: { results: flatten(DataArray[0].page.results) } }] 
console.log(flat[0].page.results)
```

The returned data is:

```
[
  { id: '1234', 'page', title: 'TextIWantA **(Text) I Dont Want**' },
  { id: '5678', 'page', title: 'ChildA TextIWant **(Text I) Dont Want**' },
  { id: '9101', 'page', title: 'ChildB TextIWant **(Text I) Dont Want**' },
  { id: 'abcd', 'page', title: 'GrandchildA TextIWant **(Text I (Dont) Want**' },
  { id: '1121', 'page', title: 'TextIWantB **(Text) I Dont Want**' }
]
```

I am making an assumption that I have to change my text to a string in order to replace it then parse it again to turn back into an object. I'm happy to learn my assumption is true or incorrect, if incorrect, how to fix to be able to remove text.

So if I try to do a replace using the following, 1) it does not work and 2) it does not differentiate for the different text to remove (perhaps I just run multiple/different replaces/filters?):

```
const veryFlat = flat;
var veryFlatData = veryFlat.map(function(x){return x.toString().replace(/ **(Text) I Dont Want**/g, '');});
var removedTextData= JSON.parse(veryFlatData);
console.log(removedTextData);
```

**Desired Result**

I want to be able to remove all of the variances of Text I Dont Want, so the end result would look like (of now it will be flattened as seen above)

```
DataArray = 
[
  {
    page: {
      results: [
        {
          id: '1234',
          title: 'TextIWantA',
          children: {
            page: {
              results: [
                {
                  id: '5678',
                  title: 'ChildA TextIWant',
                },
                {
                  id: '9101',
                  title: 'ChildB TextIWant',
                  children: {
                    page: {
                      results: [
                        {
                          id: 'abcd',
                          title: 'GrandchildA TextIWant',
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          id: '1121',
          title: 'TextIWantB',
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Each title is unique and I don't seem able to find anything to even say I've tried this or that.
I don't want to use .startswith or .length or .index and would prefer to avoid regex, and the example above using .replace doesn't seem to work.

How do I reach into these property values and rip out the text I don't want?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: I think you could do a classic DFS for this, quick search led me to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085004/iterate-through-nested-javascript-objects

Comment: Thanks @Damzaky however, I'm not seeing anything re: removal of specific text or texts, much of this speaks to iterating through arrays, which is only part of the issue. Thank you for your patience. I'm updating the initial question to further clarify what I'm trying.