# inserting item into a nested javascript object

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm, object

how does one go about inserting an item into a nested javascript array of objects (with and without using a library)? running to a problem where once you insert the item after traversing, how would you reassign it back to the original object without manually accessing the object like `data.content[0].content[0].content[0]` etc..? already tried [Iterate through Nested JavaScript Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085004/iterate-through-nested-javascript-objects) but could not get the reassignment to work

```
const data = {
    "content": [
        {
            "name": "a",
            "content": [
                {
                    "name": "b",
                    "content": [
                        {
                            "name": "c",
                            "content": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

inserting `{"name": "d", "content": []}` into the contents of `c`

```
const data = {
    "content": [
        {
            "name": "a",
            "content": [
                {
                    "name": "b",
                    "content": [
                        {
                            "name": "c",
                            "content": [{"name": "d", "content": []}]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into recursion?

Comment: It seems like [this answer at your linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8085118/1491895) directly addresses what you need to do. You just need to change `label` to `name`.

Comment: the problem isn't iterating or inserting, it's in reassigning the inserted object back to the original data structure (or new data structure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = {
  "content": [{
    "name": "a",
    "content": [{
      "name": "b",
      "content": [{
        "name": "c",
        "content": []
      }]
    }]
  }]
}

const insert = createInsert(data)

insert({
  "name": "d",
  "content": []
}, 'c')

console.log(data)

// create a new function that will be able to insert items to the object
function createInsert(object) {
  return function insert(obj, to) {
    // create a queue with root data object
    const queue = [object]
    // while there are elements in the queue
    while (queue.length) {
      // remove first element from the queue
      const current = queue.shift()
      // if name of the element is the searched one
      if (current.name === to) {
        // push the object into the current element and break the loop
        current.content.push(obj)
        break
      }
      // add child elements to the queue
      for (const item of current.content) {
        queue.push(item)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `data` be a function parameter as well?

Comment: @Barmar yes, but I don't like that, fixed with a different pattern

Comment: @Konrad nice could you explain this code? it works but i'm not able to understand why and how the original `data` is updated

Answer (score 1):

It looks like we should assume that the `name` property uniquely identifies an object in the data structure. With that assumption you could create a mapping object for it, so to map a given name to the corresponding object in the nested structure. Also keep track which is the parent of a given object.

All this meta data can be wrapped in a decorator function, so that the data object gets some capabilities to `get`, `add` and `remove` certain names from it, no matter where it is in the hierarchy:

```js
function mappable(data) {
    const map = { "__root__": { content: [] } };
    const parent = {};
    const dfs = (parentName, obj) => {
        parent[obj.name] = parentName;
        map[obj.name] = obj;
        obj.content?.forEach?.(child => dfs(obj.name, child));
    }
    
    Object.defineProperties(data, {
        get: { value(name) {
             return map[name];
        }},
        add: { value(parentName, obj) {
            this.get(parentName).content.push(obj);
            dfs(parentName, obj);
        }},
        remove: { value(name) {
            map[parent[name]].content = map[parent[name]].content.filter(obj =>
                obj.name != name
            );
            delete map[name];
            delete parent[name];
        }}
    });
    data.add("__root__", data);
}

// Demo
const data = {"content": [{"name": "a","content": [{"name": "b","content": [{"name": "c","content": []}]}]}]};

mappable(data);
data.add("c", { name: "d", content: [] });
console.log(data);
console.log(data.get("d")); // { name: "d", content: [] }
data.remove("d");
console.log(data.get("d")); // undefined
console.log(data); // original object structure
```