# Finding and updating object values with unknown path but known key

Tags: javascript

**The problem:** I have thousands of objects with wildly different levels of nesting. I need to insert data into a specific key on each of them.

While I always know said key's name, I don't know the path to it.

A few (simplified) examples:

```
// Example 1
{
    "fruits": {
        "apple": { "color": "red" },
        "orange": { "color": "orange" }
    }
}

// Example 2
{
    "fruits": {
        "round": {
            "apple": { "color": "red" },
            "orange": { "color": "orange" }
        }
    }
}


// Example 3
{
    "apple": { "color": "red" },
    "orange": { "color": "orange" }
}
```

I need to figure out a way to modify the value of, for example, "apple" across all 3 objects without knowing their specific nesting/path.

**Notes:**

- I already know how to *access the value* of this key. I need to *modify* the value.
- The key is always unique.

I had a similar issue in the past, and after digging around came upon this implementation to search for the path I need. The problem is that it works on object value, not key.

```
getPath(object: any, value: any) {
  return Object
    .keys(object)
    .reduce((r: any, k: any) => {
      const kk = Array.isArray(object) ? `[${k}]` : `${k}`;
      if (object[k] === value) {
        r.push(kk);
      }
      if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object') {
        r.push(...this.getPath(object[k], value).map((p: any) => kk + (p[0] === '[' ? '' : '.') + p));
      }
      return r;
    }, []);
}
```

How can I work around this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json), [Iterate through Nested JavaScript Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085004/iterate-through-nested-javascript-objects), [Traverse all the Nodes of a JSON Object Tree with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722668/traverse-all-the-nodes-of-a-json-object-tree-with-javascript)

Comment: It was helpful in helping me understand recursive JSON access, but other than that it does not.

Comment: Iterate recursively over the structure and compare the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to recurse through the object, modifying the parts you need to modify along the way:

```js
const changeKeyValue = (obj, keyToChange, newValue) => {

  if (obj[keyToChange]) {
    // found a child we can change!
    obj[keyToChange] = newValue
  }

  // now we recurse over any child objects:
  if (typeof(obj) == 'object') {
    for (key in obj) {
      obj[key] = changeKeyValue(obj[key], keyToChange, newValue)
    }
  }
  return obj
}

// replace the contents of any "apple" with the color:green object:
console.log(changeKeyValue(one, 'apple', {color: 'green'}))
console.log(changeKeyValue(two, 'apple', {color: 'green'}))
console.log(changeKeyValue(three, 'apple', {color: 'green'}))
```

```html
<script>
  const one = {
    "fruits": {
      "apple": {
        "color": "red"
      },
      "orange": {
        "color": "orange"
      }
    }
  }

  // Example 2
  const two = {
    "fruits": {
      "round": {
        "apple": {
          "color": "red"
        },
        "orange": {
          "color": "orange"
        }
      }
    }
  }


  // Example 3
  const three = {
    "apple": {
      "color": "red"
    },
    "orange": {
      "color": "orange"
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Good edit, thank you @mplungjan

Comment: To me this is a weird solution. I get this is a simplified approach but it looks like you are saying: "Just create a function for each fruit". I would expect a color function with 3 parameters. Object that has to change, the key and the value.

Comment: That's a fair point @Wimanicesir; I'll change it to a more general-purpose solution.