# Javascript wait() function

Tags: javascript, function, wait

I want to create a JavaScript `wait()` function.

What should I edit?

```
function wait(waitsecs) {
    setTimeout(donothing(), 'waitsecs');
}

function donothing() {
    //
}
```

Comment: You probably meant `setTimeout(donothing(), waitsecs);` but I don't see what the point of this is. `setTimeout` does not block, and you shouldn't create a spin-wait. http://stackoverflow.com/q/951021/139010

Comment: A better question is *why* do you want to have `wait` function?

Comment: This code calls donothing *immediately* and passes in a string, not the value of a parameter. `setTimeout(donothing, waitsecs)` would be a better attempt at .. a silly wrapper.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: your code should in:

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141302/is-there-a-sleep-function-in-javascript

Comment: I don't know why this is flagged as not being helpful to future users.  Just saved my ass in 2020.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Javascript isn't threaded, so a "wait" would freeze the entire page (and probably cause the browser to stop running the script entirely).

To specifically address your problem, you should remove the brackets after `donothing` in your `setTimeout` call, and make `waitsecs` a number not a string:

```
console.log('before');
setTimeout(donothing,500); // run donothing after 0.5 seconds
console.log('after');
```

But that won't stop execution; "after" will be logged before your function runs.

To wait properly, you can use anonymous functions:

```
console.log('before');
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('after');
},500);
```

All your variables will still be there in the "after" section. You shouldn't chain these - if you find yourself needing to, you need to look at how you're structuring the program. Also you may want to use `setInterval` / `clearInterval` if it needs to loop.

Comment: is this correct? `setTimeout(()=>{}, 500)`

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't edit it, you should completely scrap it.

Any attempt to make execution stop for a certain amount of time will lock up the browser and switch it to a Not Responding state. The only thing you can do is use `setTimeout` correctly.