# JQuery - pause before executing a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't make `JQuery` to wait a second before a function is executed. The `JQuery` script shows notification when `user` opens a web page. For now, all notifications show immediately but I want them to be added one by one after for example 1000 ms.

I've tried `setInterval` and `setTimeOut` but nothing worked.

My code - the notifications are still showing at the same time.

```
function showLobiboxNotification(msg, onClickUrl) {
    Lobibox.notify('info', {
        title: 'Notification',
        delay: false,
        msg: msg,
        sound: false,
        position: 'left bottom',
        showClass: 'fadeInDown',
        hideClass: 'fadeUpDown',
        rounded: 'true',
        onClickUrl: onClickUrl
    });
    setTimeout('showLobiboxNotification', 1000)
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/ajax/get-base-notifications/",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (k, message) {
                setTimeout(showLobiboxNotification(message['msg'], message['url']),1000);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: This smells of an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to pause? Your (trying) to create timeouts within timeouts, this is going to run very odd.

Comment: Have you tried triggering custom events and catching them? (See trigger method) Remember that setTimeout doesn't mean to "wait", it just adds the function call a second later to the event loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965768/set-a-delay-in-a-repeating-jquery-ajax-function

Comment: The AJAX returns something like this: {'message1':{'msg':'This is a message','url':'Some url'}, 'message2':{'msg'..... For each message1,message2... I call function above which creates a notification. What I want is to set some delay between notifications.

Comment: Or you can simply use: `showAfterPrevious: true`

Comment: Always read the docs...check this example "Show notification after previous is closed" : http://lobianijs.com/site/lobibox#lobibox-notification-examples

Comment: @Hackerman Unfortunately this isn't my problem because I want to keep them visible, just want to show them one by one after second.

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik in that case your showLobiboxNotification function could emit a custom event when it finishes. The next notification timeout would not be set until that event triggers. At the moment, if you've got 10 notifications, you'll get all of them 1 second later, because all the timeouts are set at (pretty much) the same instant in time, and all return 1 second later than that instant.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a function to `setTimeout`. You're calling the function immediately and passing the result.

```
    $.each(data, function (k, message) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            showLobiboxNotification(message['msg'], message['url'])
        },1000);
    });
```

Also, this line makes no sense.

```
setTimeout('showLobiboxNotification', 1000);
```

If the argument to `setTimeout` is a string, it needs to be a valid Javascript statement. Just giving the name of a function doesn't do anything.

Comment: `setTimeout(function() {
            showLobiboxNotification(message['msg'], message['url'])
        },1000);` this is wrapping a function within a function - not really necessary. `setTimeout(showLobiboxNotification(message['msg'], message['url']),1000);` will do just as well.

Comment: No it won't, that's the whole problem. That calls `showLobiboxNotification` **before** calling `setTimeout`.

Comment: no, it absolutely does not. Have you even tried it? Simple example: `var myVar;

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(alertFunc, 3000);
}

function alertFunc() {
    alert("Hello!");
}

myFunction();
` The alert box will show after 3 seconds. It clearly sets a timeout whereby alertFunc() is executed after 3 seconds. It's just a named function instead of an anonymous one, that's the only difference.

Comment: That's different, you didn't write `alertFunc()`, so it passes a reference to the function instead of calling it.

Comment: Try `setTimeout(alertFunc(), 3000)` to see something analogous to what he wrote.

Comment: Nonetheless, I think the issue is that he wants them to wait one second between notifications, not one second after the ajax returns. This will still just set them all to run 1 second after the ajax returns I think.

Answer (score 2):

You call the method showLobiboxNotification in same time for every notifications.

I think you can do somothing like this

```
    function showLobiboxNotification(msg, onClickUrl) {
    Lobibox.notify('info', {
        title: 'Notification',
        delay: false,
        msg: msg,
        sound: false,
        position: 'left bottom',
        showClass: 'fadeInDown',
        hideClass: 'fadeUpDown',
        rounded: 'true',
        onClickUrl: onClickUrl
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/ajax/get-base-notifications/",
        success: function (data) {
            var responseIndex = 1;
            $.each(data, function (k, message) {
                setTimeout(showLobiboxNotification(message['msg'], message['url']), responseIndex * 1000);
                responseIndex++;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see you come from a synchronous language, timeouts are async in javascript, hence you cant append a timeout or a `sleep` to the end of a function and expect the execution to freeze, because javascript doesnt do that.

wrap the whole `showLobiboxNotification` function with a timeout. this way its more modular than wrapping the calling of the function with a timeout. and a little bit less complex.

```
function showLobiboxNotification(msg, onClickUrl, delay) {
    setTimeout(function() {

      Lobibox.notify('info', {
        title: 'Notification',
        delay: false,
        msg: msg,
        sound: false,
        position: 'left bottom',
        showClass: 'fadeInDown',
        hideClass: 'fadeUpDown',
        rounded: 'true',
        onClickUrl: onClickUrl
      });
    }, 1000*delay)
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/ajax/get-base-notifications/",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (k, message) {
                showLobiboxNotification(message['msg'], message['url'], k);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

additionally if you are a fan of functional programming you can write a helper

```
callAfterDelay(delay, fn, params,) {
    setTimeout(function() {
       fn(...params)
    }, 1000*delay)
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/ajax/get-base-notifications/",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (k, message) {
                callAfterDelay(k, showLobiboxNotification, [message['msg'], message['url']];
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: if there were 10 notifications, this will just set 10 timeouts for 1 second's time, but set those timeouts all at once, so effectively they'll still all occur together (or near enough). Certainly not spaced 1 second apart.

Comment: simply added a delay, the problem with OP is that he is facing trouble with async and sync, not with code writing. as i said at the beginning of the answer, its async while he thinks its sync. anyways

Comment: he already had a delay, you just moved where the delay code is written. The issue is that he wants them to wait one second _between_ notifications, not one second after the ajax returns.

Comment: ok just spotted the 1000*delay - sorry, not reading properly this afternoon! Ok it might just work then.