# How to implement array joins in functional way?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

I have a function that joins an array of objects with a conditional separator.

```
function getSegmentsLabel(segments) {
    var separator = '-';

    var segmentsLabel = '';
    var nextSeparator = '';
    _.forEach(segments, function(segment) {
        segmentsLabel += nextSeparator + segment.label;
        nextSeparator = segment.separatorUsed ? separator : ' ';
    });
    return segmentsLabel;
}
```

**Usages:**

```
var segments = [
    {label: 'First', separatorUsed: true},
    {label: 'Second', separatorUsed: false},
    {label: 'Third', separatorUsed: true},
    {label: 'Forth', separatorUsed: true}
];

getSegmentsLabel(segments); // Result: "First-Second Third-Forth"
```

How can the above `getSegmentsLabel` function be written in a purely functional way without mutating variables? We can use lodash functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map()` method that will return new array and then `join()` to get string form that array.

```js
var segments = [
    {label: 'First', separatorUsed: true},
    {label: 'Second', separatorUsed: false},
    {label: 'Third', separatorUsed: true},
    {label: 'Forth', separatorUsed: true}
];

function getSegmentsLabel(segments) {
  return segments.map(function(e, i) {
    return e.label + (i != segments.length - 1 ? (e.separatorUsed ? '-' : ' ') : '')
  }).join('')
}

console.log(getSegmentsLabel(segments));
```

Comment: This will add space at the end.

Comment: @TheKojuEffect Updated.

Answer (score 4):

**recursion**

or instead of map/reduce/join, you can use direct recursion – the benefit here is that we don't iterate thru the collection multiple times to compute the result – oh and the program is really small so it's easy to digest

be careful of stack overflows in javascript tho; relevant: [How do I replace while loops with a functional programming alternative without tail call optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43592016/633183)

```js
var segments = [
  {label: 'First', separatorUsed: true},
  {label: 'Second', separatorUsed: false},
  {label: 'Third', separatorUsed: true},
  {label: 'Forth', separatorUsed: true}
];

const main = ([x,...xs]) =>
  x === undefined
    ? ''
    : xs.length === 0
      ? x.label
      : x.label + (x.separatorUsed ? '-' : ' ') + main (xs)
      
console.log (main (segments))
// First-Second Third-Forth
```

---

**functional programming**

that last implementation of our function is awfully specific - functional programming isn't just about using map and reduce, it's about making *meaningful* abstractions and writing *generic* procedures that can easily be reused

this example is intentionally very different from your original code with the hope that it will get you to think about programs in a different way – if this stuff interests you, as a follow up to this post, you could start reading about [monoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid).

by writing our program this way, we've represented this idea of "joinable pieces of text with conditional separators" in a *generic* text module that could be used in any other program – writers can create units of text using `Text.make` and combine them using `Text.concat`

another advantage in this program is the separator is parameter-controlled

```js
// type Text :: { text :: String, separator :: String }
const Text =
  {
    // Text.make :: (String × String?) -> Text
    make: (text, separator = '') =>
      ({ type: 'text', text, separator }),
      
    // Text.empty :: Text
    empty: () =>
      Text.make (''),
      
    // Text.isEmpty :: Text -> Boolean
    isEmpty: l =>
      l.text === '',
      
    // Text.concat :: (Text × Text) -> Text
    concat: (x,y) =>
      Text.isEmpty (y)
        ? x
        : Text.make (x.text + x.separator + y.text, y.separator),
    
    // Text.concatAll :: [Text] -> Text
    concatAll: ts =>
      ts.reduce (Text.concat, Text.empty ())  
  }

// main :: [Text] -> String
const main = xs =>
  Text.concatAll (xs) .text
  
// data :: [Text]
const data =
  [ Text.make ('First', '-'), Text.make ('Second', ' '), Text.make ('Third', '-'), Text.make ('Fourth', '-') ]
  
console.log (main (data))
// First-Second Third-Fourth
```

Comment: Awesome. I'm glad that you brought up recursion. Quite often people worry too much about using the right abstraction like `map` or `reduce` when a simple recursive function would be the most readable.

Comment: It would be nice if you added some comments to your `Text` monoid to explain how all the functions relate to each other and why you implemented them the way you did. Signatures are definitely helpful but a statement or two describing what each function does is even more helpful.

Comment: @AaditMShah thanks for the remarks; `Text.make` is a constructor to make new a new Text from an input string and optional separator – `Text.empty` constructs the empty Text, `Text.isEmpty` checks if an input Text is equivalent to the empty text, `Text.concat` joins two pieces of Text together, `Text.concatAll` joins a variable-length JavaScript Array of Text pieces together

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array for the separators and decide, if a spacer, a dash or no separator for strings at the end.

```js
const separators = [' ', '', '-'];
var getSegmentsLabel = array => array
        .map(({ label, separatorUsed }, i, a) =>
            label + separators[2 * separatorUsed - (i + 1 === a.length)])
        .join('');

var segments = [{ label: 'First', separatorUsed: true }, { label: 'Second', separatorUsed: false }, { label: 'Third', separatorUsed: true }, { label: 'Forth', separatorUsed: true }];

console.log(getSegmentsLabel(segments));
```

Comment: clever use of the static array and index – maybe initialise it outside of `getSegmentsLabel` so it's not created once per iteration tho ?

Answer (score 0):

Here I separate out the functions:

```
// buildSeparatedStr returns a function that can be used
// in the reducer, employing a template literal as the returned value
const buildSeparatedStr = (sep) => (p, c, i, a) => {
  const separator = !c.separatorUsed || i === a.length - 1 ? ' ' : sep;
  return `${p}${c.label}${separator}`;
}

// Accept an array and the buildSeparatedStr function
const getSegmentsLabel = (arr, fn) => arr.reduce(fn, '');

// Pass in the array, and the buildSeparatedStr function with
// the separator
const str = getSegmentsLabel(segments, buildSeparatedStr('-'));
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/w3xkhjdp/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `reduceRight` instead of `map` in this case:

```js
const segments = [
    {label: 'First',  separatorUsed: true},
    {label: 'Second', separatorUsed: false},
    {label: 'Third',  separatorUsed: true},
    {label: 'Forth',  separatorUsed: true}
];

const getSegmentsLabel = segments =>
    segments.slice(0, -1).reduceRight((segmentsLabel, {label, separatorUsed}) =>
        label + (separatorUsed ? "-" : " ") + segmentsLabel,
    segments[segments.length - 1].label);

console.log(JSON.stringify(getSegmentsLabel(segments)));
```

As you can see, it's better to iterate through the array from right to left.

---

Here's a more efficient version of the program, although it uses mutation:

```js
const segments = [
    {label: 'First',  separatorUsed: true},
    {label: 'Second', separatorUsed: false},
    {label: 'Third',  separatorUsed: true},
    {label: 'Forth',  separatorUsed: true}
];

const reduceRight = (xs, step, base) => {
    const x = xs.pop(), result = xs.reduceRight(step, base(x));
    return xs.push(x), result;
};

const getSegmentsLabel = segments =>
    reduceRight(segments, (segmentsLabel, {label, separatorUsed}) =>
        label + (separatorUsed ? "-" : " ") + segmentsLabel,
    ({label}) => label);

console.log(JSON.stringify(getSegmentsLabel(segments)));
```

It's not purely functional but if we treat `reduceRight` as a black box then you can define `getSegmentsLabel` in a purely functional way.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const segments = [
    {label: 'First',  separatorUsed: true},
    {label: 'Second', separatorUsed: false},
    {label: 'Third',  separatorUsed: true},
    {label: 'Forth',  separatorUsed: true}
];

const segmentsLabel = segments.reduce((label, segment, i, arr) => {
    const separator = (i === arr.length - 1) ? '' : (segment.separatorUsed) ? '-' : ' ';
    return label + segment.label + separator;
 }, '');

 console.log(segmentsLabel);
```