# Recursive version of find()

Tags: javascript, recursion, find

What i'm trying to do is make a recursive version of find, which takes an array and a test function and returns first element of an array, that passes the test. Lets look at the example:

```
function isEven(num) { return(num%2 == 0); }
var arr = [1, 3, 5, 4, 2];

function findRecursive(arr, func) {
    var p = arr.shift();
    if (func(p) == true)
        return p;
    else 
        findRecursive(arr, func);
}

findRecursive(arr, isEven);
```

By some reason i'm getting undefined. But if i change shift to pop on line 5, it correctly returns 2. What causes th problem?

Comment: you forgot to return from `findRecursive` . For your `else` clause you should `return findRecursive(arr, func);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the value of the recursive call, otherwise you return `undefined`, the standard [return value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) of a function in Javascript.

```
} else {
    return findRecursive(arr, func);
    // ^^^
}
```

You may insert a check for the length of the array, if there is no more element to check. Then you could return `undefined` intentionally.

```js
function isEven(num) { return num % 2 === 0; }

function findRight(array, fn) {
    if (!array.length) {
        return;
    }

    var p = array.pop();
    return fn(p) ? p : findRight(array, fn);
}

console.log(findRight([1, 3, 5, 4, 2], isEven)); // 2
console.log(findRight([1, 3, 5], isEven));       // undefined
```

Comment: Please put a test for if there are no even values.

Comment: @Matt, nice catch :-)

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is a looping mechanism that was born in the context of functional programming; taking it out of that context only permits a crude understanding of how recursion is meant to be used

Recursion, when used with other functional programming practices like persistent (immutable) data types and pure functions, can be expressed beautifully as a pure expression

```js
const find = (f, [x,...xs]) =>
  x === undefined
    ? x
    : f (x)
      ? x
      : find (f, xs)

const isEven = x =>
  (x & 1) === 0
      
console.log (find (isEven, [1, 3, 5, 4, 2])) // 4
console.log (find (isEven, [1, 3, 5, 7, 9])) // undefined
```

[Be careful with recursion in JavaScript, tho](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43596323/633183) – use a stack-safe looping mechanism to avoid blowing the stack on a large array

```js
const recur = (...values) =>
  ({ type: recur, values })
  
const loop = f =>
  {
    let acc = f ()
    while (acc && acc.type === recur)
      acc = f (...acc.values)
    return acc
  }
  
const find = (f, xs) =>
  loop ((i = 0) =>
    i === xs.length
      ? undefined
      : f (xs [i])
        ? xs [i]
        : recur (i + 1))

const isEven = x =>
  (x & 1) === 0

// [ 1, 2, 3, 4, ... 20000 ]
const numbers =
  Array.from (Array (2e4), (x,n) => n + 1)
  
console.log (find (isEven, numbers))     // 2

// this would have blown the stack using the first version of `find`
// but it works just fine here, thanks to loop/recur
console.log (find (x => x < 0, numbers)) // undefined
```

Comment: Your own `recur`, huh. Take that, Rich Hickey! JS is some kind of heaven for a DIY kind of programmer. :)

Comment: @WillNess overcoming some of JavaScript's "shortcomings" has taught me so much about programming ^_^