# Maximum call stack size exceeded error on converging series function

Tags: javascript, math, recursion

I'm trying to get a specific converging series function worked out in JavaScript:

```
function cnvg(sum,marker){
  if((marker--||1000)>=0){
    return cnvg(sum=(sum||0) + 1/Math.pow(-3,marker)/(2*marker+1), marker)
  } else {
    return sum;
  }
}
```

I'm expecting `cnvg()` to come back with the equivalent of `Math.PI/Math.sqrt(12)` (see image attached below) but I keep getting a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error. I thought it may be the number of iterations, so I dropped the `1000` reference to `100` then `10` and finally to `1`, but I still seem to be receiving the error.

[image]

Theoretically, once `marker` has counted down to 0 and executes the last loop it should stop and return the value of `sum`, but this doesn't seem to be the case... Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**default parameters**

in ye olde times, we wrote default parameters like this

```
function add (x, y) {
  if (x === undefined) x = 0
  if (y === undefined) y = 0
  return x + y
}
```

now with ES2015 and later, we can write them like this

```
function add (x = 0, y = 0) {
  return x + y
}
```

---

**keep things simple**

the recursive procedure can be written simply as

```js
const converge = (k = 0) =>
  k < 0
    ? 0
    : converge (k - 1) + (Math.pow (-3, -k) / (2 * k + 1))

console.log (converge (1000))          // 0.9068996821171091
console.log (Math.PI / Math.sqrt (12)) // 0.9068996821171089
```

of course, it helps readability if you abstract `sigma` first

```js
const sigma = f => k =>
  k < 0
    ? 0
    : f (k) + sigma (f) (k - 1)

// hey, this looks just like the formula you posted
const converge =
  sigma (k => Math.pow (-3, -k) / (2 * k + 1))

console.log (converge (1000))          // 0.9068996821171091
console.log (Math.PI / Math.sqrt (12)) // 0.9068996821171089
```

---

**stack safety**

I would like to point out that the stack was never in danger over overflowing – it would take a `k`-value of around 10,000 to cause an overflow

```
console.log (converge (1e4)) // RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

In this case, it doesn't matter, because even a tiny `k`-value of 10 already computes the sixth decimal place; a `k`-value of 100 computes 14 decimal places

But whatever the case, maybe you have some library that lets you compute decimals with more precision and you want to make `converge` [stack safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43596323/633183)...

```js
const recur = (...args) =>
  ({ type: recur, args })
  
const loop = f =>
  {
    let acc = f ()
    while (acc && acc.type === recur)
      acc = f (...acc.args)
    return acc
  }

// now stack-safe
const sigma = f => n =>
  loop ((acc = 0, k = n) =>
    k < 0
      ? acc
      : recur (acc + f (k), k - 1))

const converge =
  sigma (k => Math.pow (-3, -k) / (2 * k + 1))

console.log (converge (1e4))           // 0.9068996821171089 << super precise !!
console.log (Math.PI / Math.sqrt (12)) // 0.9068996821171089
```

Answer (score 5):

`marker` is never assigned in `cnvg()`, resulting in an infinite recursion. Did you mean:

```
function cnvg(sum, marker) {
  marker = (typeof(marker) === 'undefined') ? 1000 : marker;
  if (marker-- >= 0) {
    return cnvg(sum=(sum||0) + 1/Math.pow(-3,marker)/(2*marker+1), marker)
  } else {
    return sum;
  }
}
```

> but that's giving me 3 + Math.PI/Math.sqrt(12)... (3.9068996821171087)

`marker--` performs subtraction *after* the check, resulting in an additional term with `marker = -1`. Use `--marker` or `> 0`, or more clearly:

```
marker = (typeof(marker) === 'undefined') ? 1000 : marker - 1;
if (marker >= 0) {
    // ...
```

Comment: `marker--` in the question's code doesn't decrement `marker` ?

Comment: That's close... but that's giving me `3 + Math.PI/Math.sqrt(12)`... (3.9068996821171087)

Comment: @Eliseod'Annunzio May I know why you prefer the other answer?

Comment: @aaron I admire your persistence, but put simply the other answer was selected because it provided context regarding an approach I hadn't considered and was more aligned to my target result. Thank you for asking.