# recursion javascript, ask for answer

Tags: javascript, recursion

some one can help me , to solve this recursion , the question we must arrange the letter , if next letter not the sequence,it must be our output

```
function dataReducer(data) { 

}

console.log(dataReducer('abcdxefgh5wi')); // 'x,5,w'

console.log(dataReducer('opqrstu')); // ''

console.log(dataReducer('acdefghij')); // 'c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j'

console.log(dataReducer('testu')); // 'e,s,t'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: where do you see a purpose for a recusion?

Comment: @NinaScholz is recursion not *the* purpose itself? ~_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**and totally redeem yourself !**

SO likes to punish people if they don't show their work, but I'm not one to judge. I do think you will learn more if you try these problems on your own, but I know what it's like to be completely bewildered; and no good-natured soul amongst us wants to see you get stuck.

With that in mind, I really do think you can learn a lot from this answer. Please study it carefully and ask follow-up questions if you're confused.

```
const ord = c =>
  c.charCodeAt (0)

const isCharSeq = (x, y) =>
  ord (x) + 1 === ord (y)

const dataReducer = ([x, ...xs], last = null, acc = []) =>
  x === undefined
    ? acc.join (',')
  : last === null
    ? dataReducer (xs, x, acc)
  : isCharSeq (last, x)
    ? dataReducer (xs, x, acc)
  : dataReducer (xs, last, acc.concat ([x]))

console.log (dataReducer ('abcdxefgh5wi')) // 'x,5,w'
console.log (dataReducer ('opqrstu'))      // ''
console.log (dataReducer ('acdefghij'))    // 'c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j'
console.log (dataReducer ('testu'))        // 'e,s,t'
console.log (dataReducer ('a'))            // ''
console.log (dataReducer (''))             // ''
```

`dataReducer` is implemented with a proper tail call which means it can be optimised and even work on strings that are millions or billions of characters in length – even if JavaScript VM's never support this optimisation, don't worry, [you can DIY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43596323/633183).

Comment: im so soory before , cause i really newbie(cause my backgorund before in metallurgy) , then want to become progammer , then im really thankfully , i will learn alot from your answer

Comment: no need for apologies! if you have more questions, feel free to reach out.