# Recursion - Sum Nested Array

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to sum a nested array `[1,2,[3,4],[],[5]]` without using loops but I don't see what's wrong with what I have so far.

```
function sumItems(array) {
  let sum = 0;
  array.forEach((item) => {
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
      sumItems(item);
    } else {
      sum += item;
    }
  });
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: You are not storing the sum of nested arrays `sumItems(item)`. Check Dominik's answer

Comment: "I'm trying to sum a nested array [1,2,[3,4],[],[5]] without using loops" Last time I checked `forEach` is a loop.

Comment: @gforce301 technically, `forEach` is a method that uses a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with

```
 function sumItems(array) {

  let sum = 0;
  array.forEach((item) => {
    if(Array.isArray(item)) {
     sum += sumItems(item);
    } else {
    sum += item;
    }
  })
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**recursion is a functional heritage**

Recursion is a concept that comes from functional style. Mixing it with imperative style is a source of much pain and confusion for new programmers.

[To design a recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_definition), we identify the **base** and **inductive** case(s).

- base case - the list of items to sum is empty; ie, `item` is `Empty`. return `0`
- inductive case 1 - the list of items is *not* empty; ie, there must be at least one `item`. if the item is a list, return its sum *plus* the sum of the `rest` of the items
- inductive case 2 - there is at least one `item` that is *not* an array. return this item *plus* the sum of the `rest` of the items

```js
const Empty =
  Symbol ()

const sumDeep = ([ item = Empty, ...rest ] = []) =>
  item === Empty
    ? 0
    : Array.isArray (item)
      ? sumDeep (item) + sumDeep (rest)
      : item + sumDeep (rest)

console.log
  ( sumDeep ([ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, [ 6, [] ] ] ]) // 21
  , sumDeep ([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ])                     // 21
  , sumDeep ([])                                       // 0
  , sumDeep ()                                         // 0
  )
```

As a result of this implementation, all pain and suffering are removed from the program. We do not concern ourselves with local state variables, variable reassignment, or side effects like `forEach` and not using the return value of a function call.

---

**recursion caution**

And a tail-recursive version which can be made [stack-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592016/how-do-i-replace-while-loops-with-a-functional-programming-alternative-without-t/43596323#43596323). Here, we add a parameter `cont` to represent our continuation which effectively allows us sequence the order of `+` operations without growing the stack – changes in **bold**

```
const identity = x =>
  x

const sumDeep = ([ item = Empty, ...rest ] = [], cont = identity) =>
  item === Empty
    ? cont (0)
    : Array.isArray (item)
      ? sumDeep (item, a =>
         sumDeep (rest, b =>
           cont (a + b)))
      : sumDeep (rest, a =>
          cont (item + a))
```

Usage is identitcal

```
console.log
  ( sumDeep ([ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, [ 6, [] ] ] ]) // 21
  , sumDeep ([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ])                     // 21
  , sumDeep ([])                                       // 0
  , sumDeep ()                                         // 0
  )
```

**performance enhancement**

As @גלעד ברקן points out, array destructuring syntax used above (eg `...rest`) create copies of the input array. As demonstrated in his/her answer, an index parameter can be used which will avoid creating copies. This variation shows how the index technique can also be used in a tail-recursive way

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const sumDeep = (items = [], i = 0, cont = identity) =>
  i >= items.length
    ? cont (0)
    : Array.isArray (items [i])
      ? sumDeep (items [i], 0, a =>
          sumDeep (items, i + 1, b =>
            cont (a + b)))
      : sumDeep (items, i + 1, a => 
          cont (items [i] + a))

console.log
  ( sumDeep ([ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, [ 6, [] ] ] ]) // 21
  , sumDeep ([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ])                     // 21
  , sumDeep ([])                                       // 0
  , sumDeep ()                                         // 0
  )
```

Comment: `...rest` makes copies, this is inefficient memory use, although it may not be an issue, practically.

Comment: @גלעדברקן that is correct, tho copies are not retained in memory. your approach using an index is a nice workaround :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version without using loops:

```js
function f(arr, i){
  if (i == arr.length)
    return 0;
 
  if (Array.isArray(arr[i]))
    return f(arr[i], 0) + f(arr, i + 1);
   
  return arr[i] + f(arr, i + 1);
}

console.log(f([1,2,[3,4],[],[5]], 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a callback for using with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), which check if an item is an array and uses this function again for that array.

```js
function add(s, v) {
    return Array.isArray(v)
        ? v.reduce(add, s)
        : s + v;
}

var array = [1, 2, [3, 4], [], [5]];

console.log(array.reduce(add, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows;

```js
var sumNested = ([a,...as]) => (as.length && sumNested(as)) + (Array.isArray(a) ? sumNested(a) : a || 0);

console.log(sumNested([1,2,3,[4,[5,[6]]],7,[]]));
```

The function argument designation `[a,…as]` means that when the function is fed with a nested array like `[1,2,3,[4,[5,[6]]],7,[]]` then `a` is assigned to the head which is `1` and `as` is assigned to the tail of the initial array which is `[2,3,[4,[5,[6]]],7,[]]`. The rest should be easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
function arraySum (array) {
  if (array.length > 0) {
    return arraySum(array[0]) + arraySum(array.slice(1));
  }
  if (array.length === 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return array;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to some of the other solutions but might be easier for some to read:

```
 function Sum(arr) {
   if (!arr.length) return 0;
   if (Array.isArray(arr[0])) return Sum(arr[0]) + Sum(arr.slice(1));
   return arr[0] + Sum(arr.slice(1));
 }

 console.log(Sum([[1],2,[3,[4,[5,[6,[7,[8,9,10],11,[12]]]]]]])) // 78
```