# How to functional compose transforms of objects via transducers

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, function-composition, transducer

### **[Live code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/transducer?file=index.ts)**

I'm trying to learn transducers via [egghead](https://egghead.io/lessons/egghead-add-the-transducer-protocol-to-support-arbitrary-data-types-as-our-target-collections) and I think I got it until we try to compose object transformation. I have an example below that doesn't work

```
const flip = map(([k,v]) => ({[v]: k}));
const double = map(([k,v]) => ({[k]: v + v}));
seq(flip, {one: 1, two: 2}); /*?*/ {1: 'one', 2: 'two'}
seq(double, {one: 1, two: 2}); /*?*/ {'one': 2, 'two: 4}
```

but if I compose it fails:

```
seq(compose(flip, double), {one: 1, two: 2}); /*?*/ {undefined: NaN}
seq(compose(double, flip), {one: 1, two: 2}); /*?*/ {undefined: undefined}
```

How can I work with objects using transducers with fp composition?

There is quite a bit of boiler plate so I really suggest looking at the live code example to review the utils like compose, seq etc.

Comment: Note that the first thing that fails shouldn't work at all, transducers are fed to `compose` backwards. I was also under the impression that transducers only compose prior to receiving their reducing step function: `const map = xform => reducer => (accum, input) => reducer(accum, xform(input));` which only composes at the first returned function.

Comment: I understand that compose works right to left but that shouldn't matter 2 +2 or 'two'+'two' will compile just fine.  If you look at the live code for seq or sequence you'll see how the reducer is handled..

Comment: For transducers you feed them in the opposite order from normal composition. If you want to double then flip it would be `compose(double, flip)` with transducers vs. the ordinary function composition `compose(flip, double)`.

Comment: And as for your code, I'd try it with arrays of numbers first. For instance, if you take my definition of `map` above and do `const double = map(x => x * 2); const plusOne = map(x => x + 1); const append = (acc, inp) => (Array.isArray(acc) ? acc : [acc]).concat([inp]);` then do `[1,2].reduce(compose(plusOne, double)(append), [])` you get the expected `[4,6]`.

Comment: @JaredSmith seq/tranduce 100% works for Arrays of numbers. Just not objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first off thanks for going through the course.
You're having trouble composing because we've got clashing data types between the expected inputs and outputs.

When composing flip and double, the `seq` helper calls the `transduce` helper function which will convert your input object to an array of `[k,v]` entries so that it can iterate through it. It also calls your composed transform with the `objectReducer` helper to be used as the inner reducer, which just does an `Object.assign` to keep building up the accumulation.

It then iterates through the `[k,v]` entries, passing them to your composed reducer, but it's up to you to ensure you keep the data types compatible between your transforms.

In your example, `double` will get the return value of `flip`, but `double` expects a `[k,v]` array, and flip returns an object.

So you would have to do something like this:

```
const entriesToObject = map(([k,v]) => {
  return {[k]:v};
});
const flipAndDouble = compose(
  map(([k,v]) => {
    return [k,v+v];
  }),
  map(([k,v]) => {
    return [v,k];
  }),
  entriesToObject,
);

//{ '2': 'one', '4': 'two', '6': 'three' }​​​​​
```

It's a bit confusing since you have to ensure the last step returns an object and not a `[k,v]` array. This is so the `objReducer` that performs the `Object.assign` will work correctly since it expects an object as the value.
This is why I added in `entriesToObject` above.

If the `objReducer` was updated to handle `[k,v]` arrays as well as objects
as values then you could keep returning `[k,v]` arrays from your last step as well, which is a much better approach

You can see an example of how the objReducer could be rewritten here:
https://github.com/jlongster/transducers.js/blob/master/transducers.js#L766

For production use, if you use that transducer library, you can just keep treating your inputs and outputs as [k,v] arrays, which is a much better approach. For your own learning, you could try modifying the `objReducer` based on that link and you should then be able to remove `entriesToObject` from the composition above.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

**Any limitations are your own**

Others point out that you're making a mistake with the types. Each of your functions expect `[k,v]` input, but neither of them output that form - neither `compose(f,g)` or `compose(g,f)` will work in this case

Anyway, transducers are generic and need not know anything about the types of data they handle

```
const flip = ([ key, value ]) =>
  [ value, key ]

const double = ([ key, value ]) =>
  [ key, value * 2 ]

const pairToObject = ([ key, value ]) =>
  ({ [key]: value })

const entriesToObject = (iterable) =>
  Transducer ()
    .log ('begin:')
    .map (double)
    .log ('double:')
    .map (flip)
    .log ('flip:')
    .map (pairToObject)
    .log ('obj:')
    .reduce (Object.assign, {}, Object.entries (iterable))

console.log (entriesToObject ({one: 1, two: 2}))
// begin: [ 'one', 1 ]
// double: [ 'one', 2 ]
// flip: [ 2, 'one' ]
// obj: { 2: 'one' }
// begin: [ 'two', 2 ]
// double: [ 'two', 4 ]
// flip: [ 4, 'two' ]
// obj: { 4: 'two' }
// => { 2: 'one', 4: 'two' }
```

Of course we have the standard boring array of numbers and return a boring array of numbers as a possibility too

```
const main = nums =>
  Transducer ()
    .log ('begin:')
    .filter (x => x > 2)
    .log ('greater than 2:')
    .map (x => x * x)
    .log ('square:')
    .filter (x => x < 30)
    .log ('less than 30:')
    .reduce ((acc, x) => [...acc, x], [], nums)

console.log (main ([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]))
// begin: 1
// begin: 2
// begin: 3
// greater than 2: 3
// square: 9
// less than 30: 9
// begin: 4
// greater than 2: 4
// square: 16
// less than 30: 16
// begin: 5
// greater than 2: 5
// square: 25
// less than 30: 25
// begin: 6
// greater than 2: 6
// square: 36
// begin: 7
// greater than 2: 7
// square: 49
// [ 9, 16, 25 ]
```

More interestingly, we can take an input of an array of objects and return a set

```
const main2 = (people = []) =>
  Transducer ()
    .log ('begin:')
    .filter (p => p.age > 13)
    .log ('age over 13:')
    .map (p => p.name)
    .log ('name:')
    .filter (name => name.length > 3)
    .log ('name is long enough:')
    .reduce ((acc, x) => acc.add (x), new Set, people)

const data =
  [ { name: "alice", age: 55 }
  , { name: "bob", age: 16 }
  , { name: "alice", age: 12 }
  , { name: "margaret", age: 66 }
  , { name: "alice", age: 91 }
  ]

console.log (main2 (data))
// begin: { name: 'alice', age: 55 }
// age over 13: { name: 'alice', age: 55 }
// name: alice
// name is long enough: alice
// begin: { name: 'bob', age: 16 }
// age over 13: { name: 'bob', age: 16 }
// name: bob
// begin: { name: 'alice', age: 12 }
// begin: { name: 'margaret', age: 66 }
// age over 13: { name: 'margaret', age: 66 }
// name: margaret
// name is long enough: margaret
// begin: { name: 'alice', age: 91 }
// age over 13: { name: 'alice', age: 91 }
// name: alice
// name is long enough: alice
// => Set { 'alice', 'margaret' }
```

See? We can perform *any* type of transformations you want. You just need a `Transducer` that fits the bill

```
const identity = x =>
  x

const Transducer = (t = identity) => ({
  map: (f = identity) =>
    Transducer (k =>
      t ((acc, x) => k (acc, f (x))))

  , filter: (f = identity) =>
    Transducer (k =>
      t ((acc, x) => f (x) ? k (acc, x) : acc))

  , tap: (f = () => undefined) =>
    Transducer (k =>
      t ((acc, x) => (f (x), k (acc, x))))

  , log: (s = "") =>
      Transducer (t) .tap (x => console.log (s, x))

  , reduce: (f = (a,b) => a, acc = null, xs = []) =>
      xs.reduce (t (f), acc)
})
```

Full program demonstration - `.log` is added just so you can see things happening in the correct order

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const flip = ([ key, value ]) =>
  [ value, key ]
  
const double = ([ key, value ]) =>
  [ key, value * 2 ]
  
const pairToObject = ([ key, value ]) =>
  ({ [key]: value })
  
const Transducer = (t = identity) => ({
  map: (f = identity) =>
    Transducer (k =>
      t ((acc, x) => k (acc, f (x))))
      
  , filter: (f = identity) =>
    Transducer (k =>
      t ((acc, x) => f (x) ? k (acc, x) : acc))
      
  , tap: (f = () => undefined) =>
    Transducer (k =>
      t ((acc, x) => (f (x), k (acc, x))))
      
  , log: (s = "") =>
      Transducer (t) .tap (x => console.log (s, x))
      
  , reduce: (f = (a,b) => a, acc = null, xs = []) =>
      xs.reduce (t (f), acc)
})
  
const entriesToObject = (iterable) =>
  Transducer ()
    .log ('begin:')
    .map (double)
    .log ('double:')
    .map (flip)
    .log ('flip:')
    .map (pairToObject)
    .log ('obj:')
    .reduce (Object.assign, {}, Object.entries (iterable))
    
console.log (entriesToObject ({one: 1, two: 2}))
// begin: [ 'one', 1 ]
// double: [ 'one', 2 ]
// flip: [ 2, 'one' ]
// obj: { 2: 'one' }
// begin: [ 'two', 2 ]
// double: [ 'two', 4 ]
// flip: [ 4, 'two' ]
// obj: { 4: 'two' }
// => { 2: 'one', 4: 'two' }
```

**functional programming vs functional programs**

JavaScript doesn't include functional utilities like `map`, `filter` or `reduce` for other iterables like Generator, Map, or Set. When writing a function that *enables* functional programming, we can do so in a variety of ways - consider the varying implementations of `reduce`

```
// possible implementation 1
const reduce = (f = (a,b) => a, acc = null, xs = []) =>
  xs.reduce (f, acc)

// possible implementation 2
const reduce = (f = (a,b) => a, acc = null, [ x = Empty, ...xs ]) =>
  isEmpty (x)
    ? acc
    : reduce (f, f (acc, x) xs)

// possible implementation 3
const reduce = (f = (a,b) => a, acc = null, xs = []) =>
{
  for (const x of xs)
    acc = f (acc, x)
  return acc
}
```

Each implementation of `reduce` above enables functional *programming*; however, only one implementation is itself a functional *program*

1. This is just a wrapper around native `Array.prototype.reduce`. it has the same disadvantage as `Array.prototype.reduce` because it only works for arrays. Here we are happy that we can now write reduce expressions using a normal function and creating the wrapper was easy. But, if we call `reduce (add, 0, new Set ([ 1, 2, 3 ]))`, it fails because sets do not have a `reduce` method and this makes us sad.
2. This works on any iterable now, but the recursive definition means that it will overflow the stack if `xs` is significantly large - at least until JavaScript interpreters add support for tail call elimination. Here, we are happy about our representation of `reduce`, but wherever we use it our program we are sad about its Achilles heel
3. This works on any iterable just like #2, however we must trade the elegant recursive expression for the imperative-style `for` loop which ensures stack safety. The ugly details makes us sad about `reduce` but it makes us happy wherever we use it in our program.

Why is this important? Well, in the `Transducer` I shared, the `reduce` method I included is:

```
const Transducer (t = identity) =>
  ({ ...

   , reduce: (f = (a,b) => a, acc = null, xs = []) =>
      xs.reduce (t (f), acc)
  })
```

This particular implementation is closest to our `reduce` #1 above - it's a quick and dirty wrapper around `Array.prototype.reduce`. Sure our `Transducer` can perform transformations on arrays containing values of any type, but it means our Transducer can only accept arrays as input. We traded flexibility for an easier implementation.

We *could* write it closer to style #2, but then we inherit stack vulnerability wherever we use our transducer module on big data sets - which is where transducers are meant to excel in the first place. An implementation closer to #3 is itself not a functional program, but it *enables* functional programming —

The result is a module that *necessarily* utilizes some of JavaScript's imperative-style in order to enable the user to write functional-style programs in an unburdened fashion

```
const Transducer (t = identity) =>
  ({ ...

   , reduce: (f = (a,b) => a, acc = null, xs = []) =>
     {
       const reducer = t (f)
       for (const x of xs)
         acc = reducer (acc, x)
       return acc
     }
  })
```

The idea here is *you* get to write your own `Transducer` module and invent any other data types and utilities to support it. Familiarizing yourself with the trade-offs enable *you* to choose whatever is best for *your* program.

There's many ways around the "problem" presented in this section. So how can one really write functional programs in JavaScript if we're constantly having to revert to imperative style in various parts of our program? There's no silver bullet answer, but I have spent considerable time exploring various solutions. If you're this deep in the post and interested, I share some of that work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43596323/633183)

**Possibility #4**

Yep, you can leverage `Array.from` that converts any iterable to an array, which allows us to plug directly into `Array.prototype.reduce`. Now transducers that accept any iterable input, functional style, *and* an easy implementation —

A drawback of this approach is that it creates an intermediate array of values (wasted memory) instead of handling the values one-at-a-time as they come out of the iterable. Note, even solution #2 shares non-trivial drawback

```
const Transducer (t = identity) =>
  ({ ...

   , reduce: (f = (a,b) => a, acc = null, xs = []) =>
       Array.from (xs)
         .reduce (t (f), acc)
  })
```

Comment: This answer is so well said! Thank you so much naomik! Theres a lot to unpack her but it's great! Thank you so much.