# How to handle stack overflow while calling function recursively?

Tags: javascript, recursion, stack-overflow

I want to **`iterate all nodes of tree view`**

so when I have huge number of nodes at that time 
stack overflow happened so how to handle this situation as I have to  iterate all nodes.

```
var datas= getdatas();

    function treenode() {
        var item = datas.pop();

        if (item) {
        //some operation 
            treenode();
        }
    };
  treenode();
```

Comment: Where is the exit condition?

Comment: it already there  if( item )

Comment: That is not an exit/base condition... You need to add a base/exit condition there

Comment: If all you are doing is popping from an array and if that is not null, you are popping from the array again, then recursion is not appropriate, you can just do this with a for loop. Just loop over datas.length and break if you get a null entry.

Comment: @ChrisCousins ,Yes that will work if it is a simple array   but it is tree node inside tree-node structure and I have just written down overall scenario not entire code as it's big function , I have to solve this with recursive only

Comment: If your datas is tree-like then please show an example of what datas looks like. If indeed a recursive function is needed, to be sure any and all recursive functions *can be* converted to iterative functions if needed (for instance if depth is huge).

Comment: Posting questions with code like `datas = getdatas()` doesn't allow us to help you when `getdatas` remains undefined in the rest of your post. voting to close this question until you post real code with concrete data.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Guys I have found solution with settimeout function

Now I am not getting stack overflow error by moving

**simple calling call stack to event based calling**.

```
var datas= getdatas();

    function treenode() {
        var item = datas.pop();

        if (item) {
        //some operation 
         setTimeout(treenode,0);
        }
    };
  treenode()
```

Comment: [setTimeout is NOT a solution for the stack overflow problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43596323/633183)

Comment: maybe you are right but right now it's working fine for my problems