# Handling memory overflow in nested / recursive functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, recursion, promise

The following code snippet ([full code](https://gist.github.com/gvasquez95/2203d6bb78b8b47634691b69183f5cee)) has already been through a few memory-related optimizations as the initial "bad" approach caused a typical stack overflow due to the basic recursion implementation I had used, which caused the Docker container where the code run to fail due to out-of-memory issues.

The next step was to actually change the recursion into a simple `while(true)` loop, which did work but wasn't as elegant as I wanted, so finally switched back to the recursive approach but, keeping the invocation to the `transfer` recursed function as a return statement on the last line as I was told by a work colleague that NodeJS implements an optimization on such scenarios which discards all other memory usages (I don't remember the exact name of this feature, **tail recursion** perhaps?).

The problem with this last approach is that when debugging/profiling with Chrome's [built-in tool](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/), I still see the memory ramping up gradually, slowly, but definitely going up, so I'm not sure what would be the next step on this path, so all suggestions are appreciated.

```
async function transfer (backoff) {
  if (backoff > MAX_BACKOFF) {
    // reset backoff
    backoff = DEFAULT_BACKOFF
  }

  const response = await fetch(`${INBOX_URL}/next`, {
    method: HTTP_POST_METHOD,
    headers: {
      'Content-type': JSON_CONTENT_TYPE,
      Accept: JSON_CONTENT_TYPE
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      uid: AGNI_AGENT
    })
  })

  if (response.status === 502) {
    // Status 502 is a connection timeout error,
    // may happen when the connection was pending for too long,
    // and the remote server or a proxy closed it
    // let's reconnect
    backoff = DEFAULT_BACKOFF
  } else if (response.status !== 200) {
    // An error - let's show it
    console.log(`Non 200 response from AGNI: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`)
    backoff *= getFactor()
  } else {
    // Get and show the message
    const message = await response.text()
    if (message && message !== 'null') {
      publish(message)
      backoff = DEFAULT_BACKOFF
    } else {
      backoff *= getFactor()
    }
  }
  await sleep(backoff)
  return transfer(backoff)
}
```

Comment: Questions about improving working code are often better placed on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.  Yes, "tail recursion" might be the right term, but as most major JS engines don't implement the specified tail-call optimization, it's probably of limited help.  [This Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43596323/1243641) and some other answers in that question offer useful alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @ScottSauyet

Comment: Seems like I’ll be posting the question in the other community

Comment: If you do, please add a link here.  Some might be curious, even though they don't find it a good fit for this site.