# Call Stack size in recursive functions: Maximum call stack size is lower than expected

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, recursion, callstack

I'm hunting down a problem in a recursive algorithm I wrote.

This algorithm would throw a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` (in Chrome) Error on some inputs. But the call stack I tracked down was only about 6k-9k in size.

[This test](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/Z5pLM/) ([from this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7828803/2881450)) indicates a maximum call stack size of about 42k in Chrome.

---

After running some tests, I found, that having arguments on the recursive functions seems to lower the available call stack size:

**With arguments:** call stack size exceeded on **~31k** (Chrome, ~15k on Edge)

```
var recursionA = function(a, b) {
    count++;
  if (count < 100000) {
    recursionA(a, b);
  }
}
```

**Without arguments:** call stack size exceeded on **~42k** (Chrome, ~16.5k on Edge)

```
var recursionB = function() {
    count++;
  if (count < 100000) {
    recursionB();
  }
}
```

[See fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/4s2w2ubu/5/)

1. Can anyone explain, why the available call stack size is significantly lower, when the function is called with arguments.
2. Since my recursive function would require 2 arguments: How can I utilize the max call stack size of the browser?
3. Are there other factors that can potentially reduce the available call stack size?

Comment: `a` and `b` should take part of the stack IMO. Every time you call the function with those arguments, they are copied by value which forms part of the stack too.

Comment: but wouldn't they get removed from the stack immediately after?

Comment: Only after recursion ends which never happens because there's not enough space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The size of the stack is some number of **bytes**, not some number of **function calls**. Every parameter you add to a function call consumes some memory, so less stack available;
2. See 1 above
3. The variables in the function called

Answer (score 2):

I would just make another recursive function to call that recursive function and split up the duration so you dont max out the stack. Here is an example of a "callStackOptimizer" that I just wrote for a wayy over complicated and expensive fizzbuzz game written in a more functional immutable style to show you what I mean.

```
"use strict";

const isDivisibleBy = divisor => number => number % divisor === 0;

const isDivisibleBy3 = isDivisibleBy(3);
const isDivisibleBy5 = isDivisibleBy(5);
const isDivisibleBy3And5 = number => isDivisibleBy5(number) && isDivisibleBy3(number);

const rules = (bool1, bool2, bool3) => (value1, value2, value3) => number => {
    switch (true){
        case bool1(number):
            return value1;
        break;
        case bool2(number):
            return value2;
        break;
        case bool3(number):
            return value3;
        break;
        default:
            return number;
    }
};

const gameConditions = rules(
    isDivisibleBy3And5,
    isDivisibleBy3,
    isDivisibleBy5
);

const fizzBuzzResults = gameConditions(
    "FizzBuzz",
    "Fizz",
    "Buzz"
);

const game = duration => value => (action, array = []) => {
    if (duration > 0){
        const nextValue = action(value);
        return game(duration - 1)(value + 1)(action, array.concat(nextValue))
    }
    else {
        return array
    }
};

const callStackOptimizer = (duration, times = Math.ceil(duration/10000), result = []) => rules =>{
    if (times > 0){
        const value = duration/times;
        const round = game(value)(value * times - value + 1)(rules);
        return callStackOptimizer(duration - value , times - 1, result.concat(round))(rules)
    }
    else {
        return result;
    }
};

const playFizzBuzz = duration => callStackOptimizer(duration)(fizzBuzzResults);

console.log(playFizzBuzz(100000));
```