# how can I call a recursive function that calls more than 50k times in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function-call

I know the Browser Javascript Stack size limit, but is there any way to break it? while I am reading [Javascript Stack size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826992/browser-javascript-stack-size-limit) in net, I can not find a way to overcome the browser Stack size limit. Is there any tricks to do it in java-script or angular.

for example

```
var i=0;
rec(para);
function rec(para){
          if(para>=50000){

          }
          else{
            $scope.items.push(i);
            rec(i++)
          }

    }
```

is it possible to add 50000 data into an array..

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? Can you share your specific usecase?

Comment: Why do you want to push 50,000 items in your array recursively? Why not doing it iteratively?

Comment: A simple `for` loop will solve this, no need to do that recursively. If you must you can call function inside setTimeout (setImmediate for node) to clear out stack.

Comment: difff b/w both recursively and iteratively? from my understand both are same..recursively is speeder than iteratively.

Comment: 50000 recursive calls will break most any stack. Languages that let you write stuff like this actually perform tail call optimization and turn recursion into iteration behind the scenes (Haskell, Erlang and such). As for using "asynchronous recursion" as suggested below, it's OK to skim across a list of pending requests, but it'll be unbelievably slow to fill up a simple array like this.

Comment: `is it possible to add 50000 data into an array..` yes, by iteration. You need to tell us where you are stuck so that we can help you with it.

Comment: *"recursively is speeder than iteratively."* - That seems highly unlikely. Why do you think that?

Comment: @nnnnnn I have some experience in canvas for creating graphs, we always use recursive not loops(iteratively),iteratively takes time and some time it does not reponse...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use asynchronous means

```
function func1(n, callback)
{
   //do some work

   //check for exit condition
   if (n == 1)
   {
     callback();// invoke callback handler and pass the results to it.
   }
   else
   {
      setTimeout(function(){
         func1(); //call it again with modified parameters
      });
   }
}
```

One downside is that you won't be able to return the value from this method anymore.

> is it possible to add 50000 data into an array..

Yes, by Iteration. In your case, you simply need to do

```
function rec()
{
  for( var counter = 0; counter < 50000; counter++ )
  { 
    $scope.items.push(counter);
  }
}
```

Comment: recursive is coming but it takes some times, but iteration takes so long time. can we reduce a time?

Comment: @nisar I doubt that a simple iteration like I have shown above will take so much time. You need to share your actual problem so that we can help you with more specific diagnosis and answer.

Comment: just, tried one POC to check how many data we can handle in js...becoz we are going to handle one large no of DB, that returns JSON (more than 50k val)our back end is java ,We are calling API to return JSON. I planning to do with scroll.

Comment: @nisar That would also depend on your system's infra. But the solution may vary from context to context.

Answer (score 0):

If your environments allows it, try to stick with native ES5/6 methods.  You can add huge consecutive sequence of numbers into array using `fill` and `map` in a single step:

```
// assuming $scope.items is already initialized array
$scope.items = $scope.items.concat((Array(50000).fill(0).map(function(e,i){return i})));
```

http://www.2ality.com/2013/11/initializing-arrays.html, [Array.fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill), [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).