# What influences the stack headroom of IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, recursion, internet-explorer-8, stack-overflow

I'm working on a large scale React app which is required to work in IE8. The DOM reconciliation process of React recurses over the nested components and reaches stack depths of around 125, causing Stack Overflow errors.

It turns out that IE8 on the test machines have very low call stack headroom - a simple test consistently runs out after 274 levels, where as Chrome handles 17000. The test machines have 16GB RAM.
(See: [Browser Javascript Stack size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826992/browser-javascript-stack-size-limit))

My VirtualBox VM runs IE8 and handles 3200 levels - even with only 512MB assigned to the whole machine.

We're using actual IE8 - not IE11 downgraded to IE8 behaviour.

There seems to be some factor in the test machines that limits its capability to recurse.

What could cause specific installations of IE8 to have such low stack headroom?

Comment: It seems to be related to IE8 64 bits, which has much lower headroom.