# Add Numbers in array without any loop. I solved using recursion. Is there a better way?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I was asked in an interview to add numbers in an array without using loop.

I solved it using recursion.

This is my solution

```
function addNumRecursively(nums){   
    return (nums.length > 1) ? (nums[0]  + addNumRecursively(nums.slice(1))) : nums[0];  
}

console.log(addNumRecursively([1,5,4]));
```

The output is

```
rahul@rahul:~/myPractise$ node Recurssion.js 
10
```

It's working fine.

Is there a better way ?

Comment: @Teemu – Input is of type `array`

Comment: OK, maybe I didn't understand the question. `reduce` is a loop as well though.

Comment: What is your array size? Recursion will test your browser's stack size limit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826992/browser-javascript-stack-size-limit

Comment: @Teemu – Agree with you(`reduce` is loop as well).. No idea what Interviewer wanted to evaluate through this question..

Comment: @Teemu - Is there a way to do this without an implicit loop?

Comment: @nnnnnn I doubt that would be possible. But like I said, I probably haven't fully understood the question.

Comment: There is no better way than recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Array [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) as below.

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return prev + curr;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Reduce is a kind of a loop, just in disguise.
Your recursive function application is fine for a solution i think.

If this is a javascript specific question and you wanted to be a little sneaky you could do

```
function sum(arr){
  return eval(arr.join('+'))
}
```

Yes `eval` is considered evil, yes its performance is poor but this could be an alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

Javascript eval and join function will be useful for all array elements sum without using loop.

```
var total = eval([0, 1, 2, 3, 4].join("+"));
console.log(total);
```