# javascript hash table values read incorrectly

Tags: javascript

Please look at this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nu69kxyq/

This JS takes in input text file consisting of one word each line. The JS function finds longest and second longest COMPOUND word (made up of only other words in file) and total number of these compound words.

This is the exact input I'm using:

```
cat
cats
catsdogcats
dog
dogcatsdog
hippopotamuses
rat
ratcatdogcat
```

The output should be:

```
ratcatdogcat <-- longest compound word (12 characters)
catsdogcats <-- second longest compound word (11 characters)
3 <-- total number of compound words in a file
```

Total number of compound words is 3 because catsdogcats, dogcatsdog, ratcatdogcat.

I first take in all words then sort it in `wordsList`. Then I create a hash table of words for reference (to check for compound words)  in `wordDict`:

```
var wordsList = list.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.length - b.length; //sort words by length ascending
});

var wordDict = list.reduce(function(words, value, index) { //hash table from text file data
  words[value] = true;
  return words;
},{});

var isConcat = function(word) {
  for (var i = word.length; i > -1; i--){
    var prefix = word.slice(0,i);
    var suffix = word.slice(i, word.length);
    if (wordDict[prefix] === true){ //????? THIS IS ALWAYS FALSE EVEN WHEN THE KEY'S VALUE IS TRUE!!!
      if (suffix.length === 0) {
        return true; //all suffix are prefixes. word is concatenated.
      }
    return isConcat(suffix); //continue breaking remaining suffix into prefix if possible
    }
  }
  return false;
};
```

The problem is in `isConcat`, when I check against `wordDict[prefix]` to see if key's value is true, it is always false. Even when it should be true! I tried stepping through code and when key value is 'true' for 'word' key, the `if (wordDict[prefix] === true)` statement still doesn't execute because it thinks it's false. Using `data.split("\n");`, I'm able to read text file and put it in array. No issues there. So what is going wrong?

Note: I've tried using `var list = data.match(/\w+/g);` instead of `var list = data.split("\n");` to match all alphanumeric characters as words, instead of splitting them by new line, and the function worked (wordDict[prefix] worked as expected). BUT this regex skips some words when I pass in a text file of over 150,000 text words. I think I need to use `data.split("\n")`. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Properties of objects in JavaScript cannot really be looked up by prefix, if that's what you are doing. For example `obj["foo"]` will not match `obj["foobar"]`. I've not looked through the entire code yet, but I noticed you were doing `obj[prefix]`

Comment: No, the code is splitting the word in two at every character and checking, so that's not the problem

Comment: @RJK Have you put some `console.log`s in to see what the values of `wordDict`, `prefix`, and `suffix` are?

Comment: @qxz I haven't specifically used `console.log` but I have stepped through the browser console debugger to determine that when `word[prefix]` is like this: `dog : true` it still returns false. What would you suggest in this situation?

Comment: @qxz `.match` does return all, as long as you have the global flag and there are multiple matches: `"abacad".match(/a/g) //[ "a", "a", "a" ]`

Comment: My bad, didn't read carefully

Comment: @vlaz for some reason, even with the global flag in my situation, it still failed to return some words in a text file of over 150,000 words. perhaps regex isnt the way to go here?

Comment: @qxz the long file i'm using must not be written in a way where it can just return all. how can i do this using `data.split("\n")`?

Comment: Are you on Windows? is it reading the file with `\r\n` line breaks? (grrr)

Comment: Wait, if you are splitting by `\n` is the file, by any chance, encoded in the Windows format - `\r\n`?

Comment: I'm on Windows yes. I'm not 100% sure on the line breaks...should I try with `\r\n`?

Comment: Dear God, I had this exact same problem and it took me so long

Comment: Give it a go. If you open the file in Notepad++ it should tell you which line endings is it using.

Comment: Try doing `data = data.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");` to normalize it

Comment: It's in the bottom bar near the right corner - to the left of the encoding (likely UTF-8) it will say `Dos\Windows` if it uses `\r\n` or `UNIX` for `\n`. If you double-click on that value, you can switch to another, e.g., switch from Windows to UNIX

Comment: To quickly check, you can take a small file and do `console.log(JSON.stringify(fileContents));`

Comment: Also, another quick way to check, using Notepad++ - open search using Ctrl+F, switch the Search Mode to Extended and search for `\r` - if you find anything, then it's using that in the line ending

Comment: @qxz i tried using your replace and it seems to work for the input above, but it gives me `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded(…)` when I use a large file! ughhhh

Comment: @vlaz i think your guys' advice works! it just gives me an error because i guess the array is too big :(

Comment: That's because your `isConcat` function is recursive. You should rewrite it to be iterative instead, e.g. by replacing the word with the suffix and looping

Comment: Ha! that's a problem with too much recursion. There are techniques to work around that, have a look [here](http://www.integralist.co.uk/posts/js-recursion.html) also, technically, you can move away from hogging the stack by using `setTimeout` (although you need to restructure how exactly you use that). [I wrote about that recently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39459236/understanding-event-queue-and-call-stack-in-javascript/39459913#39459913) although it's more of an intro level, it might help.

Comment: how can i give you guys reputation? thank you so much for your help

Comment: @qxz what did you mean specifically by replacing the word with suffix?

Comment: See my answer. I tested it and it works the same as yours.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working implementation of `isConcat` that isn't recursive, and therefore won't have problems with stack overflow errors:

```
function isConcat(word) {
  for (var i = word.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    var prefix = word.slice(0, i);
    var suffix = word.slice(i);
    if (wordDict[prefix]) {
      if (suffix.length === 0) {
        return true; // all suffix are prefixes. word is concatenated.
      } else {
        // "restart" with suffix as the word
        word = suffix;
        i = word.length+1;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

It essentially does the same thing, except it loops/restarts instead of recursing. **Note that this will match not only compound words, but also words that exactly match a word from the list (a compound of just one word).**

Comment: I see. When I try to test in browser, it seems to hang and page becomes unresponsive. Do you think this is because we're matching exactly a word as well?

Comment: can we do something like `if(word starts with suffix)` instead of `word = suffix`

Comment: If you're using a large enough input, it might "hang" just from the processing time. You can use [`string.startsWith(prefix)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) to check if a string begins with another.

Comment: I just realized that just having `cat` and `cats` in the word list complicates the algorithm, because if it matches `cat` in `catsdog`, then it'll fail the next step because `sdog` isn't in the list