# How to implement polling in javascript

Tags: javascript, polling, long-polling, ajax-polling

I want to get data from the server every one second. Suppose that I have data.json in the server. I want to fetch that file. Can I use the following code.

```
function getData(){
    fetch('./data.json')
        .then((result) => console.log(result))
        .then(() => setTimeout(getData,1000))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

Does this method cause a stackoverflow. Cant I use fetch or do I need to use ajax. Is there a better way to implement this/

Comment: I edited it is it okay now

Comment: Does this method cause a stackoverflow since we are calling a method inside another

Comment: You need a way to handle the final response and cancel the timeout but this is the basic pattern yes.

Comment: No overflow caused here. The timer sends its arguments to a task queue, and the queue calls the callback function. In the meanwhile JS and browser are free to do other stuff.

Comment: "*Does this method cause a stackoverflow since we are calling a method inside another*" [Why doesn't an infinitely recursive async function cause stack overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56205298) | [Javascript: settimeout recursion endless stack increase?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54443801)