# Why doesn't an infinitely recursive async function cause stack overflow?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I was thinking what happens when an async function recursively calls itself infinitely. My thought was that it will not cause stack overflow. But I can't exactly point out why this is the case.

```
const foo = async () => {
    const txt = await Promise.resolve("foo");
    console.log(txt);
    foo();
}

foo();
```

The code above prints "foo" infinitely without overflowing the stack.

My idea is that the code is conceptually similar to the following, it doesn't cause stack overflow because the recursive call to `foo()` is inside the callback, the original call to `foo()` will return before that.

```
const bar = () => {
    console.log("foo");
    foo();
}

const foo = () => {
    setImmediate(bar);
}

foo();
```

I am looking for the exact answer as to what happens in the case of the async function.

Comment: It's because the recursive async call will wait for the *current* execution to finish before making a new stack frame. Hence you don't run out of stack space. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39459236/understanding-event-queue-and-call-stack-in-javascript

Comment: Yes, your explanation is correct. You would probably have a memory leak if you would `await foo()` though.

Answer (score 5):

This function is syntactic sugar for

```
const foo = () => 
  Promise.resolve(
    Promise.resolve("foo")
    .then(txt => {
      console.log(txt);
      foo();
    })
  );

foo();
```

This itself can be rewritten with less dependencies as

```
const foo = () =>
  queueMicrotask(() =>
    queueMicrotask(() => {
      console.log("foo");
      foo();
    })
  );
foo();
```

[`Window.queueMicrotask`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-queuemicrotask) is a quite new method that gives us a way to trigger the [*queue a microtask*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#queue-a-microtask) operation that Promise.resolve and hence `await` do trigger.
Basically, this operation pushes the microtask at the end of the current execution, but before the end of the current event loop.

The sixth point of the algorithm reads

> Set task's script evaluation environment settings object set to an empty set.

This is why you don't have a stack-overflow here. However, since you are never exiting the event loop, **you are blocking the browser.**

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't produce stack overflow because when you have call `foo` inside function it is not `await`ed. If you write `await foo();` then it should cause stack overflow.

Consider below two cases:

**Case 1**
Here as per your code. From `a()` it will call `foo` without `await`. So what will happen when it calls `foo()` as it is `async` function, it `would be scheduled to run after the current execution resolves. Or even more precisely, it will be queued for later execution` and immediately `a()` will also continue from next line. You can see the output that `a()` is getting ended first, it doesn't wait for call stack for `foo` to return;

```js
const foo = async () => {
    const txt = await Promise.resolve("foo");
    console.log(txt);
}

const a = async () => {
    const txt = await Promise.resolve("a");
    console.log(txt);
    foo();
    console.log("-- ENd of a() --");
}

a();
```

**Case 2**
Here inside `a()` it will call `foo` with `await`. You can see the output that `a()` is waiting for return from `foo()` then only it will continue on next line.

```js
const foo = async () => {
    const txt = await Promise.resolve("foo");
    console.log(txt);
}

const a = async () => {
    const txt = await Promise.resolve("a");
    console.log(txt);
    await foo();
    console.log("-- ENd of a() --");
}

a();
```

Comment: "*will be called in parallel thread*" there is no parallel thread - it's the same thread but would be scheduled to run after the current execution resolves. Or even more precisely, it will be queued for later execution - you could have more items on the queue to execute before the recursive call. If async recursive callse were each in was a parallel thread, then first, recursive async calls would never be deterministic 2. they can lead to an effective fork bomb.

Comment: @VLAZ, You are correct. I know that javascript is `single threaded`, there is no such thing as `parallel thread` in javascript. I just thought it would be easy to explain that way. I have updated answer. But still you have any improvement then feel free to edit. Thanks.