# Why this function doesn't cause stack overflow

Tags: javascript, stack-overflow

1. Code which doesn't cause stack overflow

```js
const s = async () => {
      await new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 1);
      });

      await s();
      console.log("exit");
};

    s();
```

2. Code causes stack overflow

```js
const s = async () => {
      await s();
      console.log("exit");
 };

    s();
```

## Question:

case 2 causing stack overflow is what i have expected, what i don't understand is what why case 1 won't. Please help me with this.

Comment: [Understanding Event Queue and Call stack in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39459236)

Comment: Oh I didn't expect we have duplicate targets for this, but I did find some good ones. Interestingly some ask "*Why does a recursive async function overflow?*" while others ask "*Why does a recursive async function not overflow?*" - it depends on the structure of the code and where the `await` is placed :-)

Comment: `async function s() { await undefined; s(); }` is all that is required for not causing a stack overflow.