# Why does apply with too many arguments throw "Maximum call stack size exceeded"?

Tags: javascript, function, apply

In Chrome and Node, the following code throws an error:

```
function noop() {}
var a = new Array(1e6)
// Array[1000000]
noop.apply(null, a)
// Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I understand why it might be a Bad Idea to pass 1 million arguments to a function, but can anyone explain why the error is `Maximum call stack size exceeded` instead of something more relevant?

(In case this seems frivolous, the original case was `Math.max.apply(Math, lotsOfNumbers)`, which is a not-unreasonable way of getting the max number from an array.)

Comment: …because function arguments are stored on the stack?

Comment: Well, yes, that's the piece of info I was missing :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Function arguments are put on the stack. You're trying to put a million arguments onto the stack, and that's more than the maximum stack size. So the error message is very relevant to the reason for the error.

Comment: For anyone wanting more specific browser stack size limitations, I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826992/browser-javascript-stack-size-limit