# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded with array.push(...)

Tags: javascript

The simple code below produces `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

```
const arr = []
for (let i = 0; i < 135000; i++) {
    arr.push(i)
}
const arr2 = []
// something else here that changes arr2
arr2.push(...arr)
```

1) Why does this happen? (I am simply adding element to an array, why does it increase stack size ?)

2) How to fix this error ? (My goal is to create a shallow copy of arr into arr2)

Comment: You might want to use [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a max number of arguments JavaScript functions can accept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747068/is-there-a-max-number-of-arguments-javascript-functions-can-accept)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The spread operator there [pushes all elements in the original array into the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42263108/why-does-apply-with-too-many-arguments-throw-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded), [just like `.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Replace_apply):

```js
const arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  arr.push(i);
}

const arr2 = [];

// Something else here that changes arr2:
arr2.push(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

Array.prototype.push.apply(arr2, arr);

console.log(arr2.join(', '));
```

So the amount of data you can handle in both cases is limited by the stack size:

```js
const arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 135000; i++) {
  arr.push(i);
}

const arr2 = [];

// Something else here that changes arr2:
arr2.push(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

Array.prototype.push.apply(arr2, arr);

console.log(arr.length, arr2.length);
```

You could do this instead:

```js
const arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 135000; i++) {
  arr.push(i);
}

let arr2 = [];

// Something else here that changes arr2:
arr2.push(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

arr2 = [...arr2, ...arr];

console.log(arr.length, arr2.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use spread operator all items of the source array are stored in the stack as arguments list, so having a large number of items (~ > 100K) will cause the this stack size exceed.

The most simple work-around is to manually push all items one by one.

You can have a helper/utility function like this:

```
function largePush(src, dest){
    const len = src.length
    for(let i = 0; i < len; i++){
        dest.push(src[i])
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
const arr = []
for (let i = 0; i < 135000; i++) {
    arr.push(i)
}
const arr2 = []
largePush(arr, arr2)
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
//I hope this will help you to make shallow copy of arr into arr2

let arr = []
for (let i = 0; i < 135000; i++) {
    arr.push(i)
}
let arr2 = []
// something else here that changes arr2
arr2=arr

console.log(arr2[0],arr[0]);
//Both 0,0
arr[0]=100

console.log(arr[0],arr2[0])

//Both 100,100
```

Comment: You are not making any copy of the original array, you are just aliasing it in another variable