# Tic Tac Toe 3D - Minimax optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery, minimax

I have this JavaScript implementation of Minimax for a Tic Tac Toe game. It works best for a 3x3 board size, but when it comes to a 3D board, page crashes. Thought PHP would be faster and tried to call Minimax by using AJAX requests to PHP but it doesn't work - Maximum execution time of 900 seconds was exceeded.

Here is the code:

```
var winningCombos   = new Array();

winningCombos[0]    = [0, 1, 2];
winningCombos[1]    = [3, 4, 5];
winningCombos[2]    = [6, 7, 8];

// Per columns
winningCombos[3]    = [0, 3, 6];
winningCombos[4]    = [1, 4, 7];
winningCombos[5]    = [2, 5, 8];

// Diagonals
winningCombos[6]    = [0, 4, 8];
winningCombos[7]    = [2, 4, 6];

// Second board
//Per lines
winningCombos[8]    = [9, 10, 11];
winningCombos[9]    = [12, 13, 14];
winningCombos[10]   = [15, 16, 17];

// Per columns
winningCombos[11]   = [9, 12, 15];
winningCombos[12]   = [10, 13, 16];
winningCombos[13]   = [11, 14, 17];

// Diagonals
winningCombos[14]   = [9, 13, 17];
winningCombos[15]   = [11, 13, 15];

// Third board
// Per lines
winningCombos[16]   = [18, 19, 20];
winningCombos[17]   = [21, 22, 23];
winningCombos[18]   = [24, 25, 26];

// Per columns
winningCombos[19]   = [18, 21, 24];
winningCombos[20]   = [19, 22, 25];
winningCombos[21]   = [20, 23, 26];

// Diagonals
winningCombos[22]   = [18, 22, 26];
winningCombos[23]   = [20, 22, 24];

// 3D Winning
winningCombos[24]   = [0, 13, 26];
winningCombos[25]   = [20, 13, 6];

// Per lines
winningCombos[26]   = [0, 10, 20];
winningCombos[27]   = [3, 13, 23];
winningCombos[28]   = [6, 16, 26];

let free            = ' ';
let boardSize       = 27;
let board           = new Array();
let activePlayer    = 'Human';
let i;
let choice;
let human;
let humanTurn;
let computer;
let computerTurn;
let humanWin = 0;
let computerWin = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#intro").addClass("hidden");
        $("#board").removeClass("hidden");
    });
});

function startGame(player) {
    for (i = 0; i < boardSize; i += 1) {
        board[i] = free;
    }

    activePlayer = 'Human';

    if (player == "X") {
        human = "X";
        humanTurn = "<p>X</p>";
        computer = "O";
        computerTurn = "<p>O</p>";
    } else {
        human = "O";
        humanTurn = "<p>O</p>";
        computer = "X";
        computerTurn = "<p>X</p>";
    }
}

function makeMove(pos) {
    if (board[pos] === free && !gameOver(board)) {
        board[pos] = human;
        document.getElementById(pos).innerHTML = humanTurn;

        if (!gameOver(board)) {
            activePlayer = 'Computer';
            makeComputerMove();
        }
    }
}

function makeComputerMove() {
    miniMax(board, 0);
    var move = choice;
    board[move] = computer;
    document.getElementById(move).innerHTML = computerTurn;
    choice = [];
    activePlayer = 'Human';
}

function score(possibleGame) {
    var score = getWinner(possibleGame);

    if (score === 3) {
        return 0;
    } else if (score === 1) {
        return -1;
    } else if (score === 2) {
        return 1;
    }
}

function miniMax(tempBoard, depth) {
    if (getWinner(tempBoard) !== 0) {
        return score(tempBoard);
    }

    depth += 1;
    var scores  = new Array();
    var moves   = new Array();
    var availableMoves = getAvailableMoves(tempBoard);
    var move, possibleGame;
    for (var i = 0; i < availableMoves.length; i += 1) {
        move = availableMoves[i];
        possibleGame = generateNewGame(move, tempBoard);
        scores.push(miniMax(possibleGame, depth));
        moves.push(move);
        tempBoard = undoMove(tempBoard, move);
    }

    var maxScore, maxScoreIndex, minScore, minScoreIndex;

    if (activePlayer === 'Computer') {
        maxScore = Math.max.apply(Math, scores);
        maxScoreIndex = scores.indexOf(maxScore);
        choice = moves[maxScoreIndex];

        return scores[maxScoreIndex];

    } else {
        minScore = Math.min.apply(Math, scores);
        minScoreIndex = scores.indexOf(minScore);
        choice = moves[minScoreIndex];

        return scores[minScoreIndex];
    }
}

function undoMove(possibleGame, move) {
    possibleGame[move] = free;
    changePlayerTurn();
    return possibleGame;
}

function getAvailableMoves(tempBoard) {
    var availableMoves = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < boardSize; i += 1) {
        if (board[i] === free) {
            availableMoves.push(i);
        }
    }
    return availableMoves;
}

function generateNewGame(move, possibleGame) {
    var piece = changePlayerTurn();
    possibleGame[move] = piece;
    return possibleGame;
}

function changePlayerTurn() {
    var turn;
    if (activePlayer === 'Computer') {
        turn = computer;
        activePlayer = 'Human';
    } else {
        turn = human;
        activePlayer = 'Computer';
    }

    return turn;
}

function gameOver(tempBoard) {
    if (getWinner(tempBoard) === 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (getWinner(tempBoard) === 1) {
        alert("You won!");
        humanWin += 1;
        if (human === "X") {
            document.getElementById("xPlayerScore").value = humanWin;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("oPlayerScore").value = humanWin;
        }
    } else if (getWinner(tempBoard) === 2) {
        alert("Computer won!");
        computerWin += 1;
        if (computer === "X") {
            document.getElementById("xPlayerScore").value = computerWin;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("oPlayerScore").value = computerWin;
        }
    } else if (getWinner(tempBoard) === 3) {
        alert("The game was a draw!");
    }
    return 1;
}

function getWinner(tempBoard) {
    for (i = 0; i < winningCombos.length; i += 1) {
        if (tempBoard[winningCombos[i][0]] === human &&
            tempBoard[winningCombos[i][1]] === human &&
            tempBoard[winningCombos[i][2]] === human) {
            return 1; // human won
        } else if (tempBoard[winningCombos[i][0]] === computer &&
            tempBoard[winningCombos[i][1]] === computer &&
            tempBoard[winningCombos[i][2]] === computer) {
            return 2; // computer won
        }
    }

    // if (tempBoard[0] === human && tempBoard[1] === human && tempBoard[2] === human) {
        //  return 1;
        // } else if (tempBoard[0] === computer && tempBoard[1] === computer && tempBoard[2] === computer) {
        //  return 2;
        // }

        // if (tempBoard[3] === human && tempBoard[4] === human && tempBoard[5] === human) {
        //  return 1;
        // } else if (tempBoard[3] === computer && tempBoard[4] === computer && tempBoard[5] === computer) {
        //  return 2;
        // }

        // if (tempBoard[6] === human && tempBoard[7] === human && tempBoard[8] === human) {
        //  return 1;
        // } else if (tempBoard[6] === computer && tempBoard[7] === computer && tempBoard[8] === computer) {
        //  return 2;
        // }

        // if (tempBoard[0] === human && tempBoard[3] === human && tempBoard[6] === human) {
        //  return 1;
        // } else if (tempBoard[0] === computer && tempBoard[3] === computer && tempBoard[6] === computer) {
        //  return 2;
        // }

        // if (tempBoard[1] === human && tempBoard[4] === human && tempBoard[7] === human) {
        //  return 1;
        // } else if (tempBoard[1] === computer && tempBoard[4] === computer && tempBoard[7] === computer) {
        //  return 2;
        // }

        // if (tempBoard[2] === human && tempBoard[5] === human && tempBoard[8] === human) {
        //  return 1;
        // } else if (tempBoard[2] === computer && tempBoard[5] === computer && tempBoard[8] === computer) {
        //  return 2;
        // }

        // if (tempBoard[0] === human && tempBoard[4] === human && tempBoard[8] === human) {
        //  return 1;
        // } else if (tempBoard[0] === computer && tempBoard[4] === computer && tempBoard[8] === computer) {
        //  return 2;
        // }

        // if (tempBoard[2] === human && tempBoard[4] === human && tempBoard[6] === human) {
        //  return 1;
        // } else if (tempBoard[2] === computer && tempBoard[4] === computer && tempBoard[6] === computer) {
        //  return 2;
        // }

    if (tempBoard.indexOf(free) >= 0) {
        return 0; // not finished yet
    }

    return 3; // the game was a draw
}

function playAgain() {
    if (getWinner(board) != 0) {
        for (var j = 0; j < boardSize; j += 1) {
            document.getElementById(j).innerHTML = "";
        }
        resetBoard();
    }
}

function resetBoard() {
    for (i = 0; i < boardSize; i += 1) {
        board[i] = free;
    }
}
```

In HTML I have divs when clicked call the `makeMove(position)` function.

I do understand how many positions and possible games it does have to generate and that the elapsed time is normal somehow, but I am wondering if there is a piece of code which can be optimized to be able to build a working Tic Tac Toe 3D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try setting a depth limit as the recursive calls will quickly add up here. Something like:

```
if(depth < MAX_DEPTH) {
   for (var i = 0; i < availableMoves.length; i += 1) {
        move = availableMoves[i];
        possibleGame = generateNewGame(move, tempBoard);
        scores.push(miniMax(possibleGame, depth));
        moves.push(move);
        tempBoard = undoMove(tempBoard, move);
   }
}
```

This may give you a decent opponent while reducing recursive calls.

If this is not an option (assuming you are still within your browser's call stack limit). You could move the heavy lifting to a webworker as this would allow it to run in the background. This would require some rewriting. See: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. So the webworker is going to have the choice generated a bit faster or it will just eliminate the page crash issue?

Comment: The webworker will not necessary make it faster but will run in the background. This will hopefully keep your browser from hanging and you could display a message like "Opponent thinking..." while it completes. However you can still get an error or possible a crash if you exceed the max call stack size. For size info see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826992/browser-javascript-stack-size-limit

Comment: Well, as I firstly heard of web workers from you, I've had to do a bit of research. I've got to a possible solution, which would be to create a new file, named init, where I have all the declarations (board, free, computer, player etc.), and a new file for the web worker (where I will put all the miniMax functionality). I call the web worker inside my `makeComputerMove` function (from above) and I send from the web worker file as response the variable called `choice`. Is it a good concept?

Comment: Glad to hear you're making progress. You're concept sounds good. Can't think of anything to change.