# javascript recursion vs while loop

Tags: javascript

quote from： https://github.com/javascript-tutorial/zh.javascript.info/blob/master/1-js/12-generators-iterators/1-generators/01-pseudo-random-generator/solution.md

```js
function* pseudoRandom(seed) {
  let value = seed;

  while(true) {
    value = value * 16807 % 2147483647
    yield value;
  }

};

let generator = pseudoRandom(1);

alert(generator.next().value); // 16807
alert(generator.next().value); // 282475249
alert(generator.next().value); // 1622650073
```

question: https://github.com/javascript-tutorial/zh.javascript.info/blob/master/1-js/12-generators-iterators/1-generators/01-pseudo-random-generator/task.md

My solution：

```js
function* pseudoRandom(seed) {
  const value = seed * 16807 % 2147483647
  yield value
  yield* pseudoRandom(value)
};

let generator = pseudoRandom(1);

alert(generator.next().value); // 16807
alert(generator.next().value); // 282475249
alert(generator.next().value); // 1622650073
```

What's the difference，thanks.

Comment: Recursion vs Iteration: https://medium.com/backticks-tildes/iteration-vs-recursion-c2017a483890#:~:text=The%20difference%20between%20them%20is,a%20certain%20condition%20is%20met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depend on how long you are planning to run this program. Your loop might go *forever* but the recursion one will throw an error.

All the function calls you do are placed in a stack. At some point, your stack is going to be full, causing a Stackoverflow Exception.

The stack limit [depends on the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7828803/5784924), but pass that limit, the Recursion one will stop in an error while the loop will continue.