# State Keeps Refreshing Hundreds of Times, Even With useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I am following Brad Traversy's React course, but it's a little old and I am using hooks and modern React for my own project, but I have a problem. When I enter the Detail page for a user, it calls a function to get the information of that user from an api. However, it turns out I am calling this function hundreds of times, even with useEffect. I will share my code, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong! If anyone can advise me on why this is re-rendering thousands of times, it would definitely be helpful. Thank you!

This is the function that is being called by Detail (setLoading is a useState function, as well as setSingleUser.

```
const getUser = username => {
    setLoading(true);

    axios
        .get(
            `https://api.github.com/users/${username}?client_id=
    ${BLAHBLAH}&client_secret=
    ${BLAHBLAH}`,
        )
        .then(res => {
            axios
                .get(
                    `https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos?per_page=5&sort=created:asc&
        client_id=${BLAHBLAH}&client_secret=
        ${BLAHBLAH}`,
                )
                .then(repores =>
                    setSingleUser({ ...res.data, repos: repores.data }),
                );
        });
    setLoading(false);
};
```

This is where I call it in Detail

```
const Detail = ({ getUser, user, loading }) => {
const { username } = useParams();
useEffect(() => {
    getUser(username);
}, [username, getUser]);
```

I have also tried useEffect with an empty dependency array and no dependency array, but it does not like any of these options.

Comment: Can you include the surrounding code of getUser in parent component and also how are you passing it to Detail component?

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because of the second parameter to useEffect `[username, getUser]`. The array of dependencies for which the useEffect must be called is being called within your useEffect directly, which then triggers the useEffect again. So, The getUser is called again. Which then calls useEffect again. And therefore its stuck in a loop. You are pretty much calling a function (getUser) again inside of a function (useEffect) that you want to call each time (getUser) is called.

You need to add an if condition in the useEffect which makes sure the getUser() function gets called only when username is false or null or undefined, or you can also change the array that you are passing to the useEffect. You can even take advantage of the `setSingleUser()` that you have in the .then(). And can add the values of those in the if check or else in the array.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, that makes a lot of sense. How do I fix this? Does the array need to be [username, getUser(username)] or something like that?

Comment: To be precise, this is not an infinite loop but a recursion. Other than an infinite loop, it stops when the stack limit of the javascript implementation is hit. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826992/browser-javascript-stack-size-limit

Answer (score 1):

As per your question, you seem to be defining getUser directly within the Parent component and passing it to child component.

Since you update state within the getUser function, the parent component will re-render and a new reference of getUser will be created. Now that you are passing `getUser` as a dependency to useEffect the useEffect runs again as getUser function has changed.

To solve this, you must memoize the getUser function in parent and you can do that using the useCallback hook

```
const getUser = useCallback(username => {
    setLoading(true);

    axios
        .get(
            `https://api.github.com/users/${username}?client_id=
    ${BLAHBLAH}&client_secret=
    ${BLAHBLAH}`,
        )
        .then(res => {
            axios
                .get(
                    `https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos?per_page=5&sort=created:asc&
        client_id=${BLAHBLAH}&client_secret=
        ${BLAHBLAH}`,
                )
                .then(repores =>
                    setSingleUser({ ...res.data, repos: repores.data }),
                );
        });
    setLoading(false);
}, []);
```

Once you do that your code should work fine

Answer (score 1):

Just include the username in the dependency array. Remove the function `getUser` since when the username is changed, the return is executed, again when getUser is called, username changes and again return is executed.

Try using this code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getUser(username);
}, [username]);
```

Comment: Wow, that worked, thank you so much! However, I now have a warning: 

Line 12:5:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getUser'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If 'getUser' changes too often, find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

How do I remove this?

Comment: If you're not using this function anywhere apart from the effect then you can move it here in the useEffect just like useEffect(() => { const getUser = () => { <whatever fucntion definition is> } }, [ ] );