# Getting this error message: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve [this leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/powx-n/) problem. In this problem, I basically need to return the power of x.

But when I run my solution it returns this error message:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

My code:

```
function myPow(base, exponent){
    if(exponent === 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if(exponent < 0){
        return (myPow(base,exponent + 1)/base);
    } else {
        return base * myPow(base,exponent-1);
    }
}

myPow(0.00001, 2147483647) // this test case is failing only I think
```

Updated code according to Luca Kiebel's suggestion

```
function myPow(base, exponent){
    if(exponent === 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if(exponent < 0){
        return (myPow(base,exponent + 1)/base);
    } else {
        return base ** myPow(base,exponent-1);
    }
}
```

Anyone please explain me where I'm making a mistake.

Comment: How was the function called? What all were the parameters?

Comment: `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` means that your function has no end and the browser stops its execution to avoid freezing. You are returning a function that calls itself as long as the exponent is not 0. You might want to get a result with Math.pow, then return that result

Comment: `return base**exponent`

Comment: @Nitheesh just added input parameters

Comment: @LucaKiebel still same error getting

Comment: `function myPow(x,y) {return x**y}` will not throw that error

Comment: nor will `Math.pow(x,n)` which passes just fine on that leet code. Why did you try to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Hey @LucaKiebel just updated the code in the question, please check. I'm still getting the same error. Please let me know if I am doing anything incorrectly.

Comment: That was not my suggestion.

Comment: @LucaKiebel I got it.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the function inside itself too many times, making the JS Engine think there's a problem, and killing it before it takes too much CPU/RAM.

Using Math.pow or a simple for loop (Instead of recursion) should fix the problem.

See [Browser Javascript Stack size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826992/browser-javascript-stack-size-limit) for how many times you can call a function inside another one

Answer (score 0):

You are basically getting that error because your function is calling itself multiple times, until a stack limit is reached.

You can try using [Math.pow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) function to achieve what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is not a good choice if you did want to roll your own raise-to-the-power function, but you can do it in a very simple loop

```js
function myPow(x,n){
  var res = 1;
  for(var i=0;i<Math.abs(n);i++)
    res = n<0 ? res/x : res * x
  return res
}

console.log(myPow(2, 10), Math.pow(2,10), 2 ** 10)
console.log(myPow(2, -2), Math.pow(2,-2), 2 ** -2)
//console.log(myPow(0.00001, 2147483647), Math.pow(0.00001,2147483647), 0.00001 ** 2147483647)
```

But as you can see from the above examples, you're simply reinventing the wheen of `Math.pow` or the `**` operator

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem in Leetcode under Recursion and got the same error. I think the issue is this problem is meant to be solved using tail recursion and since Javascript doesn't support tail recursion this will happen.