# jQuery fadeOut callback never fires

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, recursion

so I'm trying to create a really simple animation using jQuery but the callback for `fadeOut` doesn't ever happen.

Here is the code below:

```
var move = function(target, speed) {
    $(target).delay(200).animate({bottom: "-=20"},
        speed,
        function() {
            $(this).fadeOut(200, function() {
                $(this).css("bottom", "+=20");
            });
            $(this).fadeIn(200);
        }
    );
    move(target, speed);
};

move(".fa-arrow-down", 500);
```

I've tried several different things like checking it out in the console, setting various breakpoints (mainly right at `$(this).css("bottom", "+=20");`, right above this line, and right below this line).

I'm not really sure why it's not happening. Any help is appreciated and if you could please also explain what the issue actually is so I can learn too. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wTy9W/3/).

Comment: Open your developer tools to see your error. "Too much recursion." You're invoking the recursive `move()` immediately instead of in the callback.

Comment: Says the max call stack size is exceeded so yes. But I have no idea how to rectify this.

Comment: As I just said, you're invoking `move()` immediately instead of waiting for the callback. This means it invokes `move()` at a rate of frequency equal to the time it takes to invoke `.delay().animate()`, but without waiting for them to finish. In other words, `move()` will be invoked tens of thousands of times even before the first `.delay()` is finished.

Comment: Ahhhh, I see what you're saying!

Comment: I'm curious. Can it still hit the max amount of recursion? Suppose with my fix someone sat on the page long enough, would it hit the limit on recursion eventually? There's not really a base case like in C to end it and return....

Comment: I'm going to test it out >:}

Comment: Interesting, I found [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805172/what-are-the-js-recursion-limits-for-firefox-chrome-safari-ie-etc). Apparently it will come to an end eventually if you don't refresh the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move the call to `move(target, speed)` to inside the complete function of the fadeIn.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jlaw/wTy9W/4/)

```
var move = function (target, speed) {
    $(target).delay(200).animate({
        bottom: "-=20"
    },
    speed,

    function () {
        $(this).fadeOut(200, function () {
            $(this).css("bottom", "+=20");
        });
        $(this).fadeIn(200, function () {
            move(target, speed);


        });
    });
};

move(".fa-arrow-down", 500);
```

But I can't take all the credit... [cookie monster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3096782/cookie-monster) was first to see the recursion error.  Just like he said, this works because it adds a delay to each time you call move()

> As I just said, you're invoking move() immediately instead of waiting
>   for the callback. This means it invokes move() at a rate of frequency
>   equal to the time it takes to invoke .delay().animate(), but without
>   waiting for them to finish. In other words, move() will be invoked
>   tens of thousands of times even before the first .delay() is finished -- [cookie monster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3096782/cookie-monster)

Comment: Mind accepting the answer? If Cookie Monster makes one, I'll let him take the credit, but I'll take all the Rep I can get...

Comment: I got you! I literally figured it out as you posted the answer too lol

Comment: Haha... Well, thanks anyways! Good luck with your awesome animations!