# AngularJS Error: [$rootScope:infdig] caused by Filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I want to sort an Object by AngularJS Filter. But Infinite $digest error occurs when using my custom filter.

I want to make the following languages list. The list is sorted by language name.

- Albanian
- Arabic
- Dutch
- English
- Gujarati
- Hebrew Lithuanian
- Russian
- Slovak
- Urdu

The following is HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja" ng-app="MYAPP">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <title>Sort Object</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="languagesCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="language in languages | objectOrderBy:'name'">
                {{language.value.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The following is AngularJS code.

```
angular.module('MYAPP', []).

filter('objectOrderBy', function(){
    return function(obj, prop){
        var array = [];
        for(var key in obj){
            array.push({
                key: key,
                value: obj[key]
            });
        }
        return array.sort(function(o1, o2){
            return (o1.value[prop] > o2.value[prop])? 1: -1;
        });
    };
}).

controller('languagesCtrl', ["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.languages = {
        "sq": {
            "name": "Albanian"
        },
        "ar": {
            "name": "Arabic"
        },
        "nl": {
            "name": "Dutch"
        },
        "en": {
            "name": "English",
        },
        "gu": {
            "name": "Gujarati"
        },
        "he": {
            "name": "Hebrew"
        },
        "lt": {
            "name": "Lithuanian"
        },
        "ru": {
            "name": "Russian"
        },
        "sk": {
            "name": "Slovak"
        },
        "ur": {
            "name": "Urdu"
        }
    };
}]);
```

Structure of $scope.languages cannot be changed because this is served by an API server actually. Why does the error occur? Please tell me how to solve the problem.

Comment: You should create a js fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a `filter` incorrectly.

Angular `filter` works similar to the [native JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) `Array.prototype.filter()` in that it iterates over an array, performing a callback on each index.

Angular filters are actually returning the filter function, which you are doing by `return function() {}`, however within your return function you are returning another function (your sorting method).

The error `$digest() iterations reached. Aborting!` is angular-speak for [maximum recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805172/what-are-the-js-recursion-limits-for-firefox-chrome-safari-ie-etc) has been reached, and rather than continuously execute and blow the stack, the function halts, instead of causing the browsers to crash (which is good!).

To fix this, I'd suggest you either sort outside of a filter, just within a controller (which I wouldn't suggest) sort on the server-side from within your API call (that could be nice), or rework your custom filter to return a single function, rather than try and sort the entire array from within every filter call. You should look at the Angular builtin filters because one may be helpful, but you'll also be able to see how they are built.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'll lean about builtin filters.