# Trampoline recursion stack overflow

Tags: javascript, recursion, ecmascript-6

I have this recursive function `sum` which computes sum of all numbers that were passed to it.

```js
function sum(num1, num2, ...nums) {
  if (nums.length === 0) { return num1 + num2; }
  return sum(num1 + num2, ...nums);
}

let xs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) { xs.push(i); }
console.log(sum(...xs));

xs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) { xs.push(i); }
console.log(sum(...xs));
```

It works fine if only 'few' numbers are passed to it but overflows `call stack` otherwise. So I have tried to modify it a bit and use `trampoline` so that it can accept more arguments.

```js
function _sum(num1, num2, ...nums) {
  if (nums.length === 0) { return num1 + num2; }
  return () => _sum(num1 + num2, ...nums);
}

const trampoline = fn => (...args) => {
  let res = fn(...args);
  while (typeof res === 'function') { res = res(); }
  return res;
}

const sum = trampoline(_sum);

let xs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) { xs.push(i); }
console.log(sum(...xs));

xs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) { xs.push(i); }
console.log(sum(...xs));
```

While the first version isn't able to handle 10000 numbers, the second is. But if I pass 100000 numbers to the second version I'm getting `call stack overflow` error again.

I would say that 100000 is not really that big of a number (might be wrong here) and don't see any runaway closures that might have caused the memory leak.

Does anyone know what is wrong with it?

Comment: This might be relevant for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805172/what-are-the-js-recursion-limits-for-firefox-chrome-safari-ie-etc

Comment: The first will work in modern browsers thanks to tail call recursion optimization (tco)

Comment: I guess the problem is rather that the arguments overflow.

Comment: @JonasW. I know about `tco` but it doesn't work for me even on modern browser.

Comment: @Jave Thanks but it is not, I am removing deep recursion here so it should not be the case.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/22747272/3297291

Comment: call stack size for chrome/FF on my pc is around 10000-25000. Use `function sum(...args) { return args.reduce((p, c) => p + c, 0); }`. TCO is not implemented in chrome/FF or most other modern browsers.

Comment: @ASDFGerte for sure it is.

Comment: @JonasW. [ES6 browser implementation table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/). It's part of the ES6 spec, yes. That doesn't mean browsers conform to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Browsers have practical limits on the number of arguments a function can take](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22747272/3297291)

You can change the `sum` signature to accept an array rather than a varying number of arguments, and use destructuring to keep the syntax/readability similar to what you have. This "fixes" the stackoverflow error, but is increadibly slow :D

```
function _sum([num1, num2, ...nums]) { /* ... */ }
```

I.e.:, if you're running in to problems with maximum argument counts, your recursive/trampoline approach is probably going to be too slow to work with...

Comment: Tried that, slower than the worst case that I have imagined :)

Comment: A trampoline isn't slow, because it is essentially a loop. What makes a trampoline slow is a bad implementation, e.g. with destructuring assignment, which creates a new tail array for each iteration.

Comment: @ftor I didn't say trampolines are slow by definition, I said that *this* approach, which creates new arrays and functions for every recursion step, is too slow. Can you come up with a fix that lets us add 100k items recursively and comes close to the performance of a single reduce or while loop?

Comment: A trampoline is always slower than a loop, just like Javascript is slower than WebAssembly. However, a proper implemented trampoline is sufficient for most array computations and additionally, the recursive style gives you a higher level of abstraction in your code.

Comment: I don't think there's a disagreement. Maybe my answer was too concise to do justice to the many possibilities & implementations and their pros and cons... I'd still love to see an implementation of the OP's `sum` function using a trampoline that has the same clarity as their original code and is actually useable in terms of performance. If you, or anyone else, can show us some improvements in an answer you'll have my upvote!

Answer (score 3):

The other answer points out the limitation on number of function arguments, but I wanted to remark on your trampoline implementation. The long computation we're running *may* want to return a function. If you use `typeof res === 'function'`, it's not longer possible to compute a function as a return value!

Instead, encode your trampoline variants with some sort of unique identifiers

```js
const bounce = (f, ...args) =>
  ({ tag: bounce, f: f, args: args })

const done = (value) =>
  ({ tag: done, value: value })

const trampoline = t =>
{ while (t && t.tag === bounce)
    t = t.f (...t.args)
  if (t && t.tag === done)
    return t.value
  else
    throw Error (`unsupported trampoline type: ${t.tag}`)
}
```

Before we hop on, let's first get an example function to fix

```
const none =
  Symbol ()

const badsum = ([ n1, n2 = none, ...rest ]) =>
  n2 === none
    ? n1
    : badsum ([ n1 + n2, ...rest ])
```

We'll throw a `range` of numbers at it to see it work

```
const range = n =>
  Array.from
    ( Array (n + 1)
    , (_, n) => n
    )

console.log (range (10))
// [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]

console.log (badsum (range (10)))
// 55
```

But can it handle the big leagues?

```
console.log (badsum (range (1000)))
// 500500

console.log (badsum (range (20000)))
// RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

See the results in your browser so far

```js
const none =
  Symbol ()

const badsum = ([ n1, n2 = none, ...rest ]) =>
  n2 === none
    ? n1
    : badsum ([ n1 + n2, ...rest ])

const range = n =>
  Array.from
    ( Array (n + 1)
    , (_, n) => n
    )

console.log (range (10))
// [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]

console.log (badsum (range (1000)))
// 500500

console.log (badsum (range (20000)))
// RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Somewhere between `10000` and `20000` our `badsum` function unsurprisingly causes a stack overflow.

Besides renaming the function to `goodsum` we only have to encode the return types using our trampoline's variants

```
const goodsum = ([ n1, n2 = none, ...rest ]) =>
  n2 === none
    ? n1
    ? done (n1)
    : goodsum ([ n1 + n2, ...rest ])
    : bounce (goodsum, [ n1 + n2, ...rest ])

console.log (trampoline (goodsum (range (1000))))
// 500500

console.log (trampoline (goodsum (range (20000))))
// 200010000
// No more stack overflow!
```

You can see the results of this program in your browser here. Now we can see that neither recursion nor the trampoline are at fault for this program being slow. Don't worry though, we'll fix that later.

```js
const bounce = (f, ...args) =>
  ({ tag: bounce, f: f, args: args })
  
const done = (value) =>
  ({ tag: done, value: value })
  
const trampoline = t =>
{ while (t && t.tag === bounce)
    t = t.f (...t.args)
  if (t && t.tag === done)
    return t.value
  else
    throw Error (`unsupported trampoline type: ${t.tag}`)
}

const none =
  Symbol ()

const range = n =>
  Array.from
    ( Array (n + 1)
    , (_, n) => n
    )

const goodsum = ([ n1, n2 = none, ...rest ]) =>
  n2 === none
    ? done (n1)
    : bounce (goodsum, [ n1 + n2, ...rest ])

console.log (trampoline (goodsum (range (1000))))
// 500500

console.log (trampoline (goodsum (range (20000))))
// 200010000
// No more stack overflow!
```

The extra call to `trampoline` can get annoying, and when you look at `goodsum` alone, it's not immediately apparent what `done` and `bounce` are doing there, unless maybe this was a very common convention in many of your programs.

We can better encode our looping intentions with a generic `loop` function. A loop is given a function that is recalled whenever the function calls `recur`. It looks like a recursive call, but really `recur` is constructing a value that `loop` handles in a stack-safe way.

The function we give to `loop` can have any number of parameters, and with default values. This is also convenient because we can now avoid the expensive `...` destructuring and spreading by simply using an index parameter `i` initialized to `0`. The caller of the function does not have the ability to access these variables outside of the loop call

The last advantage here is that the reader of `goodsum` can clearly see the loop encoding and the explicit `done` tag is no longer necessary. The user of the function does not need to worry about calling `trampoline` either as it's already taken care of for us in `loop`

```
const goodsum = (ns = []) =>
  loop ((sum = 0, i = 0) =>
    i >= ns.length
      ? sum
      : recur (sum + ns[i], i + 1))

console.log (goodsum (range (1000)))
// 500500

console.log (goodsum (range (20000)))
// 200010000

console.log (goodsum (range (999999)))
// 499999500000
```

Here's our `loop` and `recur` pair now. This time we expand upon our `{ tag: ... }` convention using a tagging module

```
const recur = (...values) =>
  tag (recur, { values })

const loop = f =>
{ let acc = f ()
  while (is (recur, acc))
    acc = f (...acc.values)
  return acc
}

const T =
  Symbol ()

const tag = (t, x) =>
  Object.assign (x, { [T]: t })

const is = (t, x) =>
  t && x[T] === t
```

Run it in your browser to verify the results

```js
const T =
  Symbol ()

const tag = (t, x) =>
  Object.assign (x, { [T]: t })

const is = (t, x) =>
  t && x[T] === t

const recur = (...values) =>
  tag (recur, { values })

const loop = f =>
{ let acc = f ()
  while (is (recur, acc))
    acc = f (...acc.values)
  return acc
}

const range = n =>
  Array.from
    ( Array (n + 1)
    , (_, n) => n
    )

const goodsum = (ns = []) =>
  loop ((sum = 0, i = 0) =>
    i >= ns.length
      ? sum
      : recur (sum + ns[i], i + 1))

console.log (goodsum (range (1000)))
// 500500

console.log (goodsum (range (20000)))
// 200010000

console.log (goodsum (range (999999)))
// 499999500000
```

**extra**

My brain has been stuck in anamorphism gear for a few months and I was curious if it was possible to implement a stack-safe `unfold` using the `loop` function introduced above

Below, we look at an example program which generates the entire sequence of sums up to `n`. Think of it as showing the work to arrive at the answer for the `goodsum` program above. The total sum up to `n` is the last element in the array.

This is a good use case for `unfold`. We *could* write this using `loop` directly, but the point of this was to stretch the limits of `unfold` so here goes

```
const sumseq = (n = 0) =>
  unfold
    ( (loop, done, [ m, sum ]) =>
        m > n
          ? done ()
          : loop (sum, [ m + 1, sum + m ])
    , [ 1, 0 ]
    )

console.log (sumseq (10))
// [ 0,   1,   3,   6,   10,  15,  21,  28,  36, 45 ]
//   +1 ↗ +2 ↗ +3 ↗ +4 ↗ +5 ↗ +6 ↗ +7 ↗ +8 ↗ +9 ↗  ...
```

If we used an unsafe `unfold` implementation, we could blow the stack

```
// direct recursion, stack-unsafe!
const unfold = (f, initState) =>
  f ( (x, nextState) => [ x, ...unfold (f, nextState) ]
    , () => []
    , initState
    )

console.log (sumseq (20000))
// RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

After playing with it a little bit, it is indeed possible to encode `unfold` using our stack-safe `loop`. Cleaning up the `...` spread syntax using a `push` effect makes things a lot quicker too

```
const push = (xs, x) =>
  (xs .push (x), xs)

const unfold = (f, init) =>
  loop ((acc = [], state = init) =>
    f ( (x, nextState) => recur (push (acc, x), nextState)
      , () => acc
      , state
      ))
```

With a stack-safe `unfold`, our `sumseq` function works a treat now

```
console.time ('sumseq')
const result = sumseq (20000)
console.timeEnd ('sumseq')

console.log (result)
// sumseq: 23 ms
// [ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, ..., 199990000 ]
```

Verify the result in your browser below

```js
const recur = (...values) =>
  tag (recur, { values })

const loop = f =>
{ let acc = f ()
  while (is (recur, acc))
    acc = f (...acc.values)
  return acc
}

const T =
  Symbol ()

const tag = (t, x) =>
  Object.assign (x, { [T]: t })

const is = (t, x) =>
  t && x[T] === t

const push = (xs, x) =>
  (xs .push (x), xs)

const unfold = (f, init) =>
  loop ((acc = [], state = init) =>
    f ( (x, nextState) => recur (push (acc, x), nextState)
      , () => acc
      , state
      ))

const sumseq = (n = 0) =>
  unfold
    ( (loop, done, [ m, sum ]) =>
        m > n
          ? done ()
          : loop (sum, [ m + 1, sum + m ])
    , [ 1, 0 ]
    )

console.time ('sumseq')
const result = sumseq (20000)
console.timeEnd ('sumseq')

console.log (result)
// sumseq: 23 ms
// [ 0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, ..., 199990000 ]
```

Comment: @MatusDubrava I've written a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43596323/633183) that shows a variety of other ways around this. I think you will enjoy it :D

Comment: You are always so patient in explaining. Good for SO.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer already explained the issue with your code. This answer demonstrates that trampolines are sufficiently fast for most array based computations and offer a higher level of abstraction:

```js
// trampoline

const loop = f => {
  let acc = f();

  while (acc && acc.type === recur)
    acc = f(...acc.args);

  return acc;
};


const recur = (...args) =>
  ({type: recur, args});


// sum

const sum = xs => {
  const len = xs.length;

  return loop(
    (acc = 0, i = 0) =>
      i === len
        ? acc
        : recur(acc + xs[i], i + 1));
};


// and run...

const xs = Array(1e5)
  .fill(0)
  .map((x, i) => i);


console.log(sum(xs));
```

If a trampoline based computation causes performance problems, then you can still replace it with a bare loop.

Comment: Whoa, I was way too slow on this one