# ES6 proxy work-around for "TypeError: Cannot create proxy with a non-object as target"?

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, reflection, functional-programming

My last question here:
[How to store data of a functional chain of Monoidal List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51297054/how-to-store-data-of-a-functional-chain-of-monoidal-list)

had many great responses and one of them suggested to implement some sort of type structure in JavaScript:

```js
 const TYPE = Symbol();
  const typeOf = t => x => x == null
    ? x
    : Object.assign(x, {
      [TYPE]: t
    });

  const isType = t => x => x == null
    ? false
    : x[TYPE] === t;

  const Foo = x => typeOf(Foo)(x);

  console.log(
    isType(Foo)(1) // false
    , isType(Foo)([]) // false
    , isType(Foo)({}) // false
    , isType(Foo)(x => x) // false
    , isType(Foo)(true) // false
    , isType(Foo)(undefined) // false
    , isType(Foo)(null) // false
  );
 
  console.log(
    isType(Foo)(Foo(1)) // true
    , isType(Foo)(Foo([])) // true
    , isType(Foo)(Foo({})) // true
    , isType(Foo)(Foo(x => x)) // true
    , isType(Foo)(Foo(true)) // true
    , isType(Foo)(Foo(undefined)) // false
    , isType(Foo)(Foo(null)) // false
  );

  console.log(Foo(1) + Foo(2)); //3
```

While I thought this is a great idea, another member suggests this is inconsistent since [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) is a mutable operation and it should not be allowed in Functional Programming context.

In response, there is another idea to use [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) instead, so I have tried to implement the similar system by myself.

The result is unfortunately very poor since `Proxy` seems only to accept Object.

##### Works as the example

```js
var target = {};
var p = new Proxy(target, {});

p.a = 37; // operation forwarded to the target

console.log(target.a); // 37. The operation has been properly forwarded
```

##### "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create proxy with a non-object as target or handler"

```js
var target = 5;
var p = new Proxy(target, {});

p.a = 37; // operation forwarded to the target

console.log(target.a); // 37. The operation has been properly forwarded
```

I also considered to take advantage of [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), but does not work in similar manner of `Proxy`.

Basically, I recognise this is a challenge to implement [Inheritance (object-oriented programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) in functional programming with dynamic typing/ [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)　and [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)).

Therefore, I really want to make this implementation work in ES6 Proxy context.

Any great ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood what Proxy is. The whole point it to have functions in the second object to handle the "proxying" and of course the first argument **has to be an object**. Without it it will just pass whatever to the target and it will be mutated just as before. You can pass a new object as the first argument to `Object.assign` and then it will not mutate the original object. eg. `Object.assign({}, x, { [TYPE]: t })`. In ES2018 you can do `{ ...x, [TYPE]: t }`.

Comment: @Sylwester wow, this is not documented at all, and `{ ...x, ...y}` notation works in the current node.js enviroment. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @bayesian-study - Seems fairly well-documented to me. In the spec ([here](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-proxy-objects), which takes you [here](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-proxycreate), which says "1. If Type(target) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception."), [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) "**target** - A target object (can be any sort of object, including a native array, a function or even another proxy) to wrap with Proxy."

Answer (score 4):

It turns out,

- Symbol()
- Object.assign()
- Proxy

all of them are not necessary to implement [Reflection (computer programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)) at least for this topic.

See my code below:

```js
const selfAware = i => i[i] = i;
const isAware = i => (i[i] === i);

const I = i => (i === I) || (i == null)
  ? i
  : selfAware(Object(i));

const amI = i => (i === I)
  ? true
  : (i == null)
    ? false
    : isAware(i);

const ss = I(6);

console.log(ss);

console.log(ss[ss]);
//self-similarity
console.log(ss[ss][ss]);


const obj1 = {
  a: 2
};
const obj2 = I(obj1);
console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);

console.log(
  I("Hello world!").toString() //Yes, it works!
);

console.log(I(1) + I(2)); //3

console.log(
  (I) //[Function: I]
);
console.log(
  (I)(I) //[Function: I]
);
console.log(
  (I)(I)(I) //[Function: I]
);
console.log(
  (I)(I)(I)(I) //[Function: I]
);
console.log("============================");


console.log(
  amI(I) //true
  , amI(1) // false
  , amI([]) // false
  , amI({}) // false
  , amI(x => x) // false
  , amI(true) // false
  , amI(false) // false
  , amI(undefined) // false
  , amI(null) // false
);

console.log(
  amI(I(I)) // true
  , amI(I(1)) // true
  , amI(I([])) // true
  , amI(I({})) // true
  , amI(I(x => x)) // true
  , amI(I(true)) // true
  , amI(I(false)) // true
  , amI(I(undefined)) // false
  , amI(I(null)) // false
);
```