# How can I write a Regex for French number formatting? (space as thousands separator, comma as decimal separator)

Tags: jquery, regex, separator

I'm having a JQuery function that displays an amount in a text input field. Very simple...
However this is a French app, and I'm trying to build a regex for French number formatting (space as thousands separator, comma as decimal separator).

I've tried several ways... and the last try was `.replace(/(\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:$))/g, '$1 ');` but it gives no space as thousands separator, and no comma decimal separator.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Could you give an example of a source/destination format so we can see expected behavior?

Comment: Sure Joachim! INPUT = 120500.55  OUTPUT = 120 500,55 Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could reverse the string and then try `replace(/(\d{3})/g, "$1 ")` and then reverse again. Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3PRnS/1/).

**NOTE:** The `reverse` method used in the fiddle is from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958908/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-javascript).

**UPDATE**

You might have to first break the string into whole number and fractional parts, perform the above transformation, and put it back together again with a comma (if necessary). It is perhaps uglier than what you are looking for, but I couldn't think of a purely regex solution. I have updated the jsFiddle accordingly.

Comment: I guess that doesn't account for the decimal separator.

Comment: Thanks for this 1st answer mhusaini, but it doesn't give comma as decimal separator + I'm sure it's possible to have something simpler

Comment: I have updated the answer to account for comma as the decimal separator. Perhaps there is a simpler solution, but since you need to capture multiple sets of three digits and the first set can be less than three digits long, I am finding it hard to come up with a single regex that can do all of that.