# JavaScript reverse the order of letters for each word in a string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get around the following but no success:

```
var string = 'erehT era a tsav rebmun fo secruoser rof gninrael erom tpircsavaJ';

var x = string.split(' ');
for (i = 0; i <= x.length; i++) {
  var element = x[i];
}
```

element now represents each word inside the array. I now need to reverse not the order of the words but the order of each letter for each word.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you reverse a string in place in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958908/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-javascript)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var string = "erehT era a tsav rebmun fo secruoser rof gninrael erom tpircsavaJ";
// you can split, reverse, join " " first and then "" too
string.split("").reverse().join("").split(" ").reverse().join(" ")
```

Output: "There are a vast number of resources for learning more Javascript"

Comment: sorry but this reverses the order of the words, I only need the order of the letters inside each word to be reversed.. Thanks anyway...

Comment: @Alex Sorry, misunderstood your question. Updated answer by, well, just repeating the split, reverse, join to give you the answer you want

Comment: this seems to be a bit more clear or simple compared to the one showed by @plalx although a bit repetitive...

Comment: +1 @Alex, I like the simplicity of this solution as well, however mine performs slightly better with huge strings. But this one performs well with small strings, so it depends what you are doing. http://jsperf.com/reverse-word-letters/2

Comment: Note also that this solution fails for characters outside the BMP. It also fails for combining characters.

Comment: @Lobo Can you please explain this line of code, how does it reverse? how does the algorithm works?

Answer (score 8):

You can do it like this using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.prototype.reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse).

```
var result = string.split(' ').map(function (item) {
    return item.split('').reverse().join('');
}).join(' ');
```

> what's the map function doing there?

It traverses the array created by splitting the initial string and calls the `function (item)` we provided as argument for each elements. It then takes the return value of that function and push it in a new array. Finally it returns that new array, which in our example, contains the reversed words in order.

Comment: That works perfectly but what's the map function doing there?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
let stringToReverse = "tpircsavaJ";

stringToReverse.split("").reverse().join("").split(" ").reverse().join(" ")
```

//let keyword allows you declare variables in the new ECMAScript(JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following.

```
var string = "erehT era a tsav rebmun fo secruoser rof gninrael erom tpircsavaJ";

arrayX=string.split(" ");
arrayX.sort().reverse();
var arrayXX='';
arrayX.forEach(function(item){
items=item.split('').sort().reverse();
arrayXX=arrayXX+items.join('');
});
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=arrayXX;
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript split with [regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/qpi3pC/2):

**Note**: `([\s,.])` The capturing group matches whitespace, commas, and periods.

```js
const string = "oT eb ro ton ot eb, taht si a noitseuq.";

function reverseHelper(str) {
  return str.split(/([\s,.])/).
  map((item) => {
    return item.split``.reverse().join``;
  }).join``;
}

console.log(reverseHelper(string));
```