# Function that takes string and returns string reversed

Tags: javascript

What is wrong with the following code

```
function FirstReverse(str) { 
  var backwards = "";
  for(var i = str.length; i>=0;i--){
     backwards += str[i];
      }
  str = backwards;  
  return str; 

}

// keep this function call here 
// to see how to enter arguments in JavaScript scroll down
FirstReverse(readline(str));
```

this is the first challenge on http://coderbyte.com/CodingArea/GuestEditor.php?ct=First%20Reverse&lan=JavaScript the only error it returns is `ReferenceError: readline is not defined`, but `readline` is what the site says to use. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function reverse(s){
    return s.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

Caveats : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16776621/1636522.

Answer (score 1):

1. The `readline` function doesn't take any arguments. Simply remove `str` and keep the line like this

   ```
   FirstReverse(readline());
   ```
2. You are starting your loop with `i = str.length`, so when you do `str[i]` for the first time, you will get `undefined`. So, you should be starting from `str.length - 1`.
3. Also you can return the `backwards` directly, you don't have to store it in `str` back, before returning.

---

```
function FirstReverse(str) {
    var backwards = "";
    for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        backwards += str[i];
    }
    return backwards;
}
```

Also, I tested with these changes and it works.

Comment: @OneKitten I tested it on their site. They do some preprocessing it seems.

Comment: Ah, it's one of those coding example sites -- that would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The first time the loop body is executed, `i` will have the value of `str.length`. That is one beyond the last element of the `str`, which is at index `str.length - 1`.

Fixed code:

```
function FirstReverse(str) { 
  var backwards = "";
  for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     backwards += str[i];
  }
  str = backwards;  
  return str; 
}
```

Comment: i understand my error and this makes sense, but it still returns the same error, could it be a bug on the site itself?

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
function FirstReverse(str) { 
  var backwards = "";
  for(var i = str.length - 1; i>=0;i--){
     backwards += str[i];
      }
  str = backwards;  
  return str; 

}
```

because when indexing it begins from 0 to the length minus one of the string

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function FirstReverse(str) { 
  var backwards = "";
  for(var i = str.length - 1; i>=0; --i){
     backwards += str[i];
  }
  return backwards;  
}
```

Comment: still got the same error, i think there is something wrong with the sites example

Answer (score 0):

You can apply this below code.

```
function FirstReverse(str) { 
  var backwards = "";
  for(var i = str.length - 1; i>=0; --i){
     backwards += str[i];
  }
  return backwards ;  


}
   
// keep this function call here 
console.log(FirstReverse(readline()));
```

It means when you write something on input, it will give you a reverse result.