# reversing a string, why the quotations?

Tags: javascript

I saw another stackoverflow thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958908/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-javascript/16776621#16776621)

one of the answers given was

```
function reverse(s){
    return s.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

so my question is, why are there quotation marks for `split` and `join` but not `reverse`?

Comment: Learn JavaScript First.

Comment: The close vote is not necessary, the question has a very finite answer is not to broad.

Comment: Also I don't know why so many down votes for this question, granted it could have been answered by the author if he did some research but, AFAIK this is still a valid question on SO, and anyone is encouraged to ask programming questions here which do now fall under one of the 'close' reasons.

Comment: @LiviuM. The help text for a downvote _literally begins_ __this question does not show any research effort__.

Answer (score 5):

That's because the 3 functions are different:

```
String.split( delimiter ); // delimiter = split by what

Array.reverse(); // reverse an array
                 // unlike other array functions such as sort() or join()
                 // there is no other option to specify because the function
                 // does only one thing only one way

Array.join( join_string ); // join_string = what string to insert
                           // between elements
```

Whenever you have doubts about how functions work read the documentation:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Not all functions require one argument. Some take none. Some take two or three. Some have optional arguments.

Answer (score 4):

`reverse()` is called on an array. The result of `split("")` being an array of letters (strings of one letter each to be precise).

Answer (score 1):

`.split("")` Will spit a string based on a given parameter. in this case `""` means no delimiter so it will split on each char and return an array of char. then `reverse()` method is call on that array. once it reversed then we have to join it back to the string. `join("")` will do that task for you. in this case `""` means no delimiter for join so array will join each char together.