# Number format with regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, number-formatting

I have a number is 1205000000, I want display at 1.205.000.000

```
number.toString().replace(/(\d{3})/g, "$1.").toString()
```

but result is 120.500.000.0
I don't want reverse a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of correcting your regular expression *(obviously for **integer** values only):*

```js
number.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/g, '$1.');
```

[image: www.regexper.com] 
[» Detailed Regex Explanation](http://regex101.com/r/wF2xI6/1)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to [reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958908/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-javascript) the string before your manipulation and ther reverse it again. Like so:

```
var number = 1205000000;

function reverse(s) {
    return s.split("").reverse().join("");
}

var str = reverse(reverse(number.toString()).replace(/(\d{3})/g, "$1."));
alert(str);
```

See this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2nzq8ejr/).

**EDIT:**
See the comments. Its a bit dirty but for that specific number it will work. The link posted by @Artyom Neustroev as a comment under you question seems a whole lot better than this here.

Comment: Won't work correctly with float numbers.

Comment: please take care of `120500000` (or `100`) for that matter

Comment: Yeah, you are both right. I've added your concerns as an edit to my answer, but for that specific case, it would work, so i wont delete the answer if you don't mind.