# Cant able to find out the palindrome string/number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written following code to find out palindrome number/string.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function Palindrom() {
var rev="";
var str= document.getElementById("name1").value;


for ( var i=str.lenght; i>=0; i--)
{

var rev=rev + str.charAt(i);
}

if (str == rev)
{
alert ("Enter value is palindrome");
}

else
{alert ("Value is not palindrome");}

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
Enter String:<input type="text" name="Name" id="name1">
<button type="button" onclick="Palindrom();"> Check it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

However, it is giving the o/p of else statement even i am entering palindrome string in the box.. I don;t think there is something wrong. please correct the code and explain what was wrong. Thank you, sameer

Comment: `str.lenght` ??typo  , also you should start with `str.length-1`

Comment: Royi :) got it... Miss-spelled the length property..

Answer (score 1):

You should start reversing at str.length - 1 (because the strings are zero-indexed (that is, the first position in the string is 0 instead of 1 and, so, for a 5-character string, the last position is 4, not 5). Also, why not use some existing functions instead of reinventing the weel?

```
x = '1234'
y = x.split('').reverse().join('')
alert(y)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for all strings, e.g `aña`  http://jsfiddle.net/nsp4d95y/  Here there is an explaination with fix: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16776621/1414562

Comment: I doubt the op needs to use this for an incredibly rich set of characters. Also, I expect the `for` not to work in that situation either.

Comment: That's true, none solution posted here work for special unicoded characters. For usual string, i prefer your answer over looping way, imho

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in `str.lenght`

Also you should start your loop with `str.length-1`

Working example : http://jsbin.com/ponoro/2/edit

Example :

```
function Palindrom() {
var rev="";
var str= '12342554321';


for ( var i=str.length-1; i>=0; i--)
{

var rev=rev + str.charAt(i);
}
alert(rev)
if (str == rev)
{
alert ("Enter value is palindrome");
}

else
{alert ("Value is not palindrome");}

}
```

Comment: why should use str.length-1?? please explain.. I am beginner of javascript.. I think string index start with 0 and that's why we are separating one from total length..

Comment: How many iteration would be with  3 chars ? `3&2&1&0` do you see the mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly str.length function returns the actual length of the array and not the offset i.e. speaking in a simple language the last index of the array is 1 minus the length of the array...

Answer (score 0):

Edit your typo ".length"
... or could also eliminate the loop if you wish.

```
function checkPalindrome(num){
    if(num == parseInt(num.toString().split('').reverse().join(''))){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why not `return (num == parseInt(num.toString().split('').reverse().join('')))` ?

Comment: That works too --good tip Nathan