# Remove last x characters until a specific character

Tags: google-bigquery

I got this string **/uk-en/contact-us/frequently-asked-questions/your-trip/there-wi-fi-access-in-the-eurostar-terminals-and-board-your-trains** and I need to get just the last part of the URL (until the last /).
Then I want to replace '-' with a space. The strings are not with the same number of characters.

How can I do?

Thank you!

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using BigQuery linked with GA

Comment: It sounds like bigquery can use JavaScript functions in which case you could try [something like](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958908/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Solution using BigQuery functions:

```
select regexp_replace(last(split(x, "/")), "-", " ") from
(select 
  "/uk-en/contact-us/frequently-asked-questions/your-trip/there-wi-fi-access-in-the-eurostar-terminals-and-board-your-trains"
  as x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I tried in SQL Server

```
 DECLARE @s VARCHAR(max)= '/uk-en/contact-us/frequently-asked-questions/your-trip/there-wi-fi-access-in-the-eurostar-terminals-and-board-your-trains'

 SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@s),CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(@s)),LEN(REVERSE(@s))))+REVERSE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@s),1,CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(@s))-1),'-',' '))
```

Sorry this was for SQL Server

did you try using split in big query

SPLIT('str' [, 'delimiter'])    Returns a set of substrings as a repeated string. If delimiter is specified, the SPLIT function breaks str into substrings, using delimiter as the delimiter.

Comment: BigQuery doesn't recognize the REVERSE function.