# Putting an input for palindrome number

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, validation, input

I have been trying to make an input that gets a array and checks if it is a palindrome number or not, by the locations of the numbers (with `i = 0` and `j = array.length`).

I just don't know how can I continue from here and what is wrong with my code.

That is my function:

```
function isPalindrome() {
    var input;
    var array = input.split("");

    var i = 0;
    var j = array.length;

    while (i < j) {
        if (array[i] != array[j]) {
            return false;  
        } else {
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

[I created a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/qajzadby/9/)

Comment: You're not using function parameters correctly. This is actually pretty common in people who start programming for the first time.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: you need to pass something into the function `isPalindrome(input){ // la la la }`

Comment: why don't you reverse the string and check to see if the 2 strings are the same ? Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958908/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-javascript) and pick your reverse implementation

Comment: As an optimisation to Edi's answer,when you take the reverse of the string and compare the two strings ,you need to check only till half of the string length

Comment: @user4517807 is that really an optimization though? Checking for equality of two strings is pretty efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few things in your fiddle that needed fixing

1. You're not reading the *value* of the field. Change this `var input = $("#input")` to `var input = $("#input").val()`
2. You're not passing the value to the function. Change this:

   ```
   function isPalindrome() {
        var input;
   ```

   to

   ```
   function isPalindrome(input) {
   ```
3. You set `j` equal to `array.length`, in order to read the last element in the array that should be `array.length-1`

Here's an updated, and working, fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qajzadby/10/

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can you tell me why do i need to use array.length-1 and not array.length? didn't really get the problem. for exmaple- 123321. the right "1" is array.length, isn't it?

Comment: An array with values `1,2,3,3,2,1` has a length of 6. However, arrays are zero based so the last element has the index `5`.

Answer (score 4):

A few things. You didn't have a parameter for your isPalindrome method. You weren't passing the value to it either. You also can reverse the array and check it without doing extra loops. ie: 1221 reversed == 1221 (true) whereas 1223 reversed != 3221 (false)

See my [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/qajzadby/9/)

```
$("#checkPalindrome").click(function () {
    // added .val() here so we get the value.
    var inp = $("#input").val();
    $("#result").html("("+isPalindrome(inp)+")");

});

// added param str
function isPalindrome(str) {
   // split the string into an array, reverse it, join it into a string again
   // then check if it's equal to the original string passed.
   return str.split('').reverse().join('') == str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

allright so this took me a little bit longer than expected, but my go at this is like this :

```
$("#checkPalindrome").click(function () {
var number = $("#input").val();
$("#result").text(isPalindrome(number));

});
function isPalindrome(number) {
    return String(number) == String(number).split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qajzadby/11/
love me some 1 line functions >:)
also fixed your number retrieval

Comment: I think `.val()` is just going to return a string since it's coming from an input. Probably no need to cast it as a string. Not that it's hurting anything.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `input` in `undefined`. If it may be equal to some string, then looks like this line:

```
if (array[i] != array[j])
```

is the culprit, because `j` is equal to `array.length` initially. You should take `array[j - 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things are going here...

1)You are not calling your function with some input
  eg->`isPalindrome(myPalindromeNumber)`

2)`array.length` will return the total number of elements in te array so you should be indexing as `array[i]!=array[j-1]`

Comment: Your last point is not true, OP original code works just as well on odd-length as even-length input

Answer (score 0):

```
/* TODO: check if a number is a פילנדום on input's content change */
$("#checkPalindrome").click(function () {
    var input = $("#input").val();
    $("#result").text(isPalindrome(input));

});

function isPalindrome(input) {

    var array = input.split("");

    var i = 0;
    var j = array.length;

    for(i=0;i < j ;i++){
        if(array[i] != array[j-i-1]){
            return false;
       }
    }

    return true;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5795u98o/)**