# Javascript - Reverse words in a sentence

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

Please refer - https://jsfiddle.net/jy5p509c/

```
var a = "who all are coming to the party and merry around in somewhere";

res = ""; resarr = [];

for(i=0 ;i<a.length; i++) {

if(a[i] == " ") {
    res+= resarr.reverse().join("")+" ";
    resarr = [];
}
else {
    resarr.push(a[i]);
}   
}
console.log(res);
```

The last word does not reverse and is not outputted in the final result. Not sure what is missing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958908/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-javascript

Comment: It doesn't reverse because there's no space character after the last word.

Comment: Its because last word is only getting pushed in a[i] but not getting reversed since coming out of for loop

Comment: Bugs in this implementation aside, it's far too overcomplicated. Split, reverse, and join does the job.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It problem is your `if(a[i] == " ")` condition is not satisfied for the last word

```js
var a = "who all are coming to the party and merry around in somewhere";

res = "";
resarr = [];

for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (a[i] == " " || i == a.length - 1) {
    res += resarr.reverse().join("") + " ";
    resarr = [];
  } else {
    resarr.push(a[i]);
  }
}

document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(res))
```

---

You can also try a shorter

```js
var a = "who all are coming to the party and merry around in florida";

var res = a.split(' ').map(function(text) {
  return text.split('').reverse().join('')
}).join(' ');

document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(res))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know wich one is the best answer I'll live you mine and let you decide, here it is :

```
console.log( 'who all are coming to the party and merry around in somewhere'.split('').reverse().join('').split(" ").reverse().join(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line before console log, you will get as expected

```
res+= resarr.reverse().join("")+" ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var a = "who all are coming to the party and merry around in somewhere";

//split the string in to an array of words
var sp = a.split(" ");

for (i = 0; i < sp.length; i++) {
    //split the individual word into an array of char, reverse then join 
    sp[i] = sp[i].split("").reverse().join("");
}

//finally, join the reversed words back together, separated by " "
var res = sp.join(" ");

document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(res))
```