# Is there any way to extend an native object for a single variable?

Tags: javascript

I wanna get the next functionality:

```
var newString = String;
newString.prototype.reverse = function () {
    return this.split("").reverse().join("")
}

var a = 'hello';
var b = newString('hello');
a.reverse();//reverse is not a function
b.reverse();//olleh
```

try extend .prototype before add function and doesn't work, i don't even know if it is possible.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: ["How do you reverse a string in place in JavaScript?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958908/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-javascript) has exactly what you are looking for in some of the lower answers.

Comment: Are you looking for `b.reverse = function(){...}`?

Comment: @SLaks you can absolutely do that, and his code works fine as is. There's just no reason to create `newString` if you're augmenting the prototype anyways.

Comment: @Aweary: He's trying to _not_ modify normal strings.  He can't do that.

Comment: reverse it's just an quick example, i wanna get some methods just for 'b', unmodified te prototype String of all my variables.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
var newString = function(initialVal) {
    var val = new String(initialVal);
    val.reverse = function () {
        return this.split("").reverse().join("")
    };
    return val;
};

var a = 'hello';
var b = newString('hello');
a.reverse();//reverse is not a function
b.reverse();//olleh
```

Comment: That can work, but it change the 'typeof b' to 'object'.

Comment: @burgarin yeah, it's definitely not ideal to use the string constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for:

```
String.prototype.reverse = function () {
    return this.split("").reverse().join("")
}

var a = 'hello';
alert(a.reverse());
```

Note that extending built in objects like "String" is highly controversial at best.

Comment: Your code does nothing else than OP's; `newString.prototype === String.prototype`