# When .unshift-ing an array to a string, how do I avoid having the "," between each character?

Tags: javascript

I am working on the project of reversing a string and am getting commas in between each character in the reversed string.

`var testString = prompt("Enter a 'string'");

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = testString;

var reverse = function(string){
    var gnirts = [];
    for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
        gnirts.unshift(string[i]);
    };
    gnirts.toString();
    document.getElementById("revString").innerHTML = gnirts;
};

reverse(testString);`
```

I entered "Honky Toast" in the prompt and "t,s,a,o,T, ,y,k,n,o,H" was returned.  Why am I getting the ","s and how do I avoid them?

Comment: because it's an array?

Comment: try this gnirts.join('');

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you reverse a string in place in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958908/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-javascript)

Comment: I think your problem is not `why do I get commas`, it is `how to reverse a string`. You didn't say you didn't want to use built-in functions like `Array.reverse()`, so the question above should solve your problem.

Comment: gnirts.join(' '); gives me "t s a o T y k n o H" when what I would like is "tsaoT yknoH"

AH!  My bad, I had a space inside the ''.

Comment: I know there are lots of ways to reverse a string.  I am more interested in learning about what is going on and how to fix this specific issue, rather than to simply reverse the string without actually learning any more.

Answer (score 2):

Use join, and pass an empty string as separator.

REPL:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

x.join()
'1,2,3,4,5'

x.join('')
'12345'
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling `gnirts.toString();` You should use `join`. Array's implementation of toString separates each item with a comma.

```
var reverse = function(string){
    var gnirts = [];
    for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
        gnirts.unshift(string[i]);
    };
    document.getElementById("revString").innerHTML = gnirts.join('');
};
```

Comment: This did it.  When/why would one want an array to a string separated by commas?

Comment: Display purposes. If I had an array of numbers `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and I printed it, I wouldn't normally want it to print as `1234`. If it did, I couldn't discern whether it was originally `[1, 2, 3, 4]` or `[12, 34]`, or any other combination of those four digits.